# What is @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

What is the purpose and usage of `@ModelAttribute` in Spring MVC?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib and http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html

Comment: I think this is a useful question, because it allows readers to get more information (including examples) than official Spring documentation provides.

Comment: Check this writeup here. http://thespringthing.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-does-modelattribute-work.html

Answer (score 439, accepted):

[`@ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) refers to a property of the Model object (the M in MVC ;)
so let's say we have a form with a form backing object that is called "Person"
Then you can have Spring MVC supply this object to a Controller method by using the `@ModelAttribute` annotation:

```
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person){
    person.getStuff();
}
```

On the other hand the annotation is used to define objects which should be part of a Model.
So if you want to have a Person object referenced in the Model you can use the following method:

```
@ModelAttribute("person")
public Person getPerson(){
    return new Person();
}
```

This annotated method will allow access to the Person object in your View, since it gets automatically added to the Models by Spring.

See ["Using @ModelAttribute"](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args).

Comment: @fasseg You don't actually need `@ModelAttribute` in your first case.

Comment: @Neil  When do you need to use `@ModelAttribute` in method attributes?

Comment: @Ryan see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688135/modelattribute-annotation-when-to-use-it/26916920#26916920

Comment: you should include how Person is populated and how this method is called.

Comment: it is not good only we speak about concepts. it is better we speak about details. fo example we speak what is the difference between @ModelAttribute and no anootation parameter. an when need we to use it?

Answer (score 153):

I know this is an old thread, but I thought I throw my hat in the ring and see if I can muddy the water a little bit more :)

I found my initial struggle to understand `@ModelAttribute` was a result of Spring's decision to combine several annotations into one. It became clearer once I split it into several smaller annotations:

For parameter annotations, think of `@ModelAttribute` as the equivalent of `@Autowired + @Qualifier` i.e. it tries to retrieve a bean with the given name from the Spring managed model. If the named bean is not found, instead of throwing an error or returning `null`, it implicitly takes on the role of `@Bean` i.e. Create a new instance using the default constructor and add the bean to the model.

For method annotations, think of `@ModelAttribute` as the equivalent of `@Bean + @Before`, i.e. it puts the bean constructed by user's code in the model and it's always called before a request handling method.

Figuratively, I see `@ModelAttribute` as the following (please don't take it literally!!):

```
@Bean("person")
@Before
public Person createPerson(){
  return new Person();
}

@RequestMapping(...)
public xxx handlePersonRequest( (@Autowired @Qualifier("person") | @Bean("person")) Person person, xxx){
  ...
}
```

As you can see, Spring made the right decision to make `@ModelAttribute` an all-encompassing annotation; no one wants to see an annotation smorgasbord.

Comment: Hm, @Bean is singleton by default. I'm not sure the same concepts apply here.

Comment: Absolutely not. I'm just using simpler annotations to explain this complex annotation. Please take my explanation conceptually, not literally.

Comment: @Zombies add `@Scope("request")` then :)

Answer (score 39):

So I will try to explain it in simpler way. Let's have:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

As described in the Spring MVC documentation - the **@ModelAttribute** annotation can be used on **methods** or on **method arguments**. And of course we can have both use at the same time in one controller.

**1.Method annotation**

```
@ModelAttribute("cities")
 public List<String> checkOptions(){
 return new Arrays.asList(new[]{"Sofia","Pleven","Ruse"});//and so on
}
```

Purpose of such method is to add attribute in the model. So in our case **cities** key will have the list `new Arrays.asList(new[]{"Sofia","Pleven","Ruse"})` as value in the Model (you can think of Model as map(key:value)).  **@ModelAttribute** methods in a controller are invoked before **@RequestMapping** methods, within the same controller.

Here we want to add to the Model common information which will be used in the form to display to the user. For example it can be used to fill a HTML select:

[image]

**2.Method argument**

```
public String findPerson(@ModelAttriute(value="person") Person person) {
    //..Some logic with person
    return "person.jsp";
}
```

An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. So in this case we expect that we have in the Model  **person** object as key and we want to get its value and put it to the method argument **Person person**. If such does not exists or (sometimes you misspell the (value="persson")) then Spring will not find it in the Model and will create empty Person object using its defaults. Then will take the request parameters and try to data bind them in the Person object using their names.

```
name="Dmitrij"&countries=Lesoto&sponsor.organization="SilkRoad"&authorizedFunds=&authorizedHours=&
```

So we have name and it will be bind to Person.name using setName(String name). So in

```
//..Some logic with person
```

we have access to this filled name with value "Dimitrij".

Of course Spring can bind more complex objects like Lists, Maps, List of Sets of Maps and so on but behind the scene it makes the data binding magic.

3. We can have at the same time model annotated method and request method handler with @ModelAttribute in the arguments. Then we have to union the rules.
4. Of course we have tons of different situations - @ModelAttribute methods can also be defined in an @ControllerAdvice and so on...

Answer (score 34):

For my style, I always use @ModelAttribute to catch object from spring form jsp. for example, I design form on jsp page, that form exist with commandName

```
<form:form commandName="Book" action="" methon="post">
      <form:input type="text" path="title"></form:input>
</form:form>
```

and I catch the object on controller with follow code

```
public String controllerPost(@ModelAttribute("Book") Book book)
```

and every field name of book must be match with path in sub-element of form

Comment: The `catch` verb exactly describes the work that `@ModelAttribute` has done. Nice.

Comment: Best answer of the year.

Comment: But is it necessary ? This is still working without using @ModelAttribute annotation.

Comment: `modelAttribute` is the new way; `commandName` is the old way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495616/difference-between-modelattribute-and-commandname-attributes-in-form-tag-in-spri

Answer (score 34):

I know I am late to the party, but I'll quote like they say,
"better be late than never". So let us get going,
Everybody has their own ways to explain things, let me try to sum it up and simple it up for you in a few steps with an example;
Suppose you have a simple form, `form.jsp`:

```html
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="student">
  First Name : <form:input path="firstName" /> 
  <br/><br/>
  Last Name : <form:input path="lastName" />
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

`<form:input path="firstName" />` `<form:input path="lastName" />` These are the fields/properties in the Student class. When the form is called/initialized their getters are invoked. On form submit their setters are invoked, and their values are transferred in the bean that was indicated with `modelAttribute="student"` in the form tag.

We have `StudentController` that includes the following methods:

```java
@RequestMapping("/showForm")
// `Model` is used to pass data between controllers and views
public String showForm(Model theModel) {
    // attribute name, value
    theModel.addAttribute("student", new Student());
    return "form";
}
   
@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent) {
    System.out.println("theStudent :"+ theStudent.getLastName());
    return "form-details";
}

//@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent
//Spring automatically populates the object data with form data 
//all behind the scenes
```

Now finally we have a `form-details.jsp`:

```html
<b>Student Information</b>
${student.firstName}
${student.lastName}
```

So back to the question What is `@ModelAttribute` in Spring MVC?
A sample definition from the source for you,
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation
The `@ModelAttribute` is an annotation that binds a method parameter or method return value to a named model attribute and then exposes it to a web view.

What actually happens is it gets all the values of your form those were submitted by it and then holds them for you to bind or assign them to the object. It works like the `@RequestParameter` where we only get a parameter and assign the value to some method argument.
The difference is that `@ModelAttribute` holds all form data rather than a single parameter. It creates a bean for you which holds the data submitted in the form.

To recap the whole thing:

Step 1:
A request is sent and our method `showForm()` runs and a model, a temporary bean, is set with the name `student` and forwarded to the form:
`theModel.addAttribute("student", new Student());`

Step 2:
Form attribute `modelAttribute="student"` defines that on form submission the model will update the student and will hold all parameters of the form.

Step 3:
On form submission the `processForm()` method is invoked with parameter `@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent`: the values being hold in the form with `modelAttribute="student"` were fetched and assigned to the fields in the `Student` object.

Step 4:
And then we use it as we bid, just like showing it on the page etc like I did

I hope it helps you to understand the concept. Thanks

Comment: Superb explanation, this is what I was looking for all over the Internet. Thank God, I came across your response

Comment: Best explanation till now

Comment: Good explanation. But what about `@ModelAttribute` on method level?

Answer (score 16):

Take any web application whether it is Gmail or Facebook or Instagram or any other web application, it's all about exchanging data or information between the end user and the application or the UI and the back end application. Even in Spring MVC world there are two ways to exchange data:

1. from the Controller to the UI, and
2. from the UI to the Controller.

What we are interested here is how the data is communicated from the UI to Controller. This can also be done in 2 ways:

1. Using an HTML Form
2. Using Query Parameters.

Using an HTML Form:
Consider the below scenario,

[image: Form Submission Representation]

When we submit the form data from the web browser, we can access that data in our Controller class as an object. When we submit an HTML form, the Spring Container does four things. It will,

1. first read all the data that is submitted that comes in the request using the **request.getParameter** method.
2. once it reads them, it will convert them into the appropriate Java type using **integer.parseInt**, **double.parseDouble** and all the other parse methods that are available based on the data type of the data.
3. once parsed, it will create a object of the model class that we created. For example, in this scenario, it is the user information that is being submitted and we create a class called User, which the Container will create an object of and it will set all the values that come in automatically into that object.
4. it will then handover that object by setting the values to the Controller.

To get this whole thing to work, we'll have to follow certain steps.

[image: Internal working]

We first need to define a model class, like User, in which the number of fields should exactly match the number of fields in the HTML form. Also, the names that we use in the HTML form should match the names that we have in the Java class. These two are very important. Names should match, the number of fields in the form should match the number of fields in the class that we create. Once we do that, the Container will automatically read the data that comes in, creates an object of this model, sets the values and it hands it over to the Controller. To read those values inside the Controller, we use the **@ModelAttribute** annotation on the method parameters. When we create methods in the Controller, we are going to use the @ModelAttribute and add a parameter to it which will automatically have this object given by the Container.

Here is an example code for registering an user:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "regResult";
}
```

Hope this diagrammatic explanation helped!

Comment: Is there a need for the line mode.AddAttribute("user", user)???  Cos via the @ModelAttribute("user"), i thought the  argument is automatically bind to the model attribute "user".

Answer (score 4):

@ModelAttribute can be used as the method arguments / parameter or before the method declaration.
 The primary objective of this annotation to bind the request parameters or form fields to an model object

Ref. http://www.javabeat.net/modelattribute-spring-mvc/

Answer (score 4):

Annotation that binds a method parameter or method return value to a named model attribute, exposed to a web view.

```
public String add(@ModelAttribute("specified") Model model) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is used for data binding purposes in Spring `MVC`. Let you have a jsp having a form element in it e.g

> on `JSP`

`<form:form  action="test-example" method="POST"    commandName="testModelAttribute"> </form:form>`

(Spring Form method, Simple form element can also be used)

> On Controller Side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test-example", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView testExample(@ModelAttribute("testModelAttribute") TestModel testModel, Map<String, Object> map,...) {

}
```

Now when you will submit the form the form fields values will be available to you.

Answer (score 1):

`@ModelAttribute` will create a attribute  with the name specified by you `(@ModelAttribute("Testing") Test test) as Testing`  in the given example ,Test being the bean test being the reference to the bean and Testing will be available in model so that you can further use it on jsp pages for retrieval of values that you stored in you `ModelAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

@ModelAttribute simply binds the value from jsp fields to Pojo calss to perform our logic in controller class. If you are familiar with struts, then this is like populating the formbean object upon submission.

Answer (score 0):

The ModelAttribute annotation is used as part of a Spring MVC Web application and can be used in two scenarios.

First of all, it can be used to inject data into a pre-JSP load model. This is especially useful in ensuring that a JSP is required to display all the data itself. An injection is obtained by connecting one method to the model.

Second, it can be used to read data from an existing model and assign it to the parameters of the coach's method.

refrence https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-mvc%E2%80%99s

Answer (score 0):

At the Method Level

1.When the annotation is used at the method level it indicates the purpose of that 
   method is to add one or more model attributes

```
@ModelAttribute
public void addAttributes(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("india", "india");
}
```

At the Method Argument
 1. When used as a method argument, it indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. When not present and  should be first instantiated and then added to the model and once present in the model, the arguments fields should be populated from all  request parameters that have matching names So, it binds the form data with a bean.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String submit(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
  return "employeeView";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Models are used in MVC Spring (MVC = Model, View, Controller). This said, **models are used together with "views"**.

What are these views? ***Views can be though as "html pages that are generated by our backend framework (Spring in our case) with some variable data in some parts of the html page".***

So we have the model, which is an entity containing the data do be "injected" into the view.

There are several "view" libraries that you can work with Spring: among which, JSP, Thymeleaf, Mustache and others.

For example, let us assume we are using Thymeleaf (they are all similar. What's more, Spring does not even know, except for JSP, with which view libraries he is working with. All the models are served through the Servlet of Spring. This means that the Spring code will be the same for all these view libraries. The only thing you need to change is the syntax of such html pages, which are located in resources/static/templates)

```
resources/static/templates   //All our view web pages are here
```

A Controller takes care of the routes. Let's say for example we have our site hosted on localhost:8080. We want a route (URL) showing us the students. Let us say that this is available at localhost:8080/students. The controller that will do this is StudentController:

```
@Controller  //Not @RestController
   public class StudentController {

   @GetMapping(/students)
   public String getStudentView() {
       return "student";
   }
}
```

What this code does, is saying that, if we are going to

> localhost:8080/students

then the method getStudentView() is called. But notice it should return a String. However, when working with a view library, and the controller is annotated with @Controller (and not @RestController), what spring does is looking for an html view page with the name of the String that the method returns, in our case it will look for the view at

> /resources/static/templates/student.html

This is good enough for static pages without data. However, if we need a dynamic page with some data, Spring offers another big advantage: the method above getStudentView(), will also pass, under the hood, a model to our view "student.html". Our model will contain data that we can access in the file "student.html" using the specific syntax from our view library. E.g., with thymeleaf:

```
<div th:text="${attribute1}"> </div>
```

This will access the attribute "attribute1" of our model.
**We can pass different data through our model. This is done by assigning it various attributes. There are different ways of assigning attributes, with @ModelAttribute:**

```
@Controller  //Not @RestController
   public class StudentController {

   @ModelAttribute(name = "attribute1")
   public int assignAttribute1() {
      return 123454321
   }   // Think it as "model.attribute1 = 123454321"

   @GetMapping(/students)
   public String getStudentView() {
       return "student";
   }
}
```

The code above will assign to the model (created under the hood), an attribute with name "attribute1" (think it as of a key), with value 12354321. Something like "model.attribute1 = 123454321".

Finally, the model is passed to the view when we go to the url

> localhost:8080/students

Notice: all the methods annotated with @ModelAttribute are invoked before a view is returned. The model, once all the attributes are created, is passed to our view. simply put, after the method getStudentView() is called, all the method with @ModelAttribute are called.

This being said, the html code written above, will be viewed from the browser as:

```
<div> 123454321 </div> // th:text is a command of 
//THymeleaf, and says to substitute the text
// between the tags with the attribute "attribute1" 
// of our model passed to this view.
```

This is the basic usage of @ModelAttribute.

There is also another important use case:

The model might be needed in the opposite direction: i.e., from the view to the controller. In the case described above, the model is passed from the controller to the view. However, let us say that the user, from our html page, sends back some data. We can catch it with out model attributes, @ModelAttribute. This has already been described by others