# @ModelAttribute annotation, when to use it?

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

Lets say we have an entity Person, a controller PersonController and an edit.jsp page (creating a new or editing an existing person)

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editPerson(@RequestParam("fname") String fname, Model model) {
    if(fname == null || fname.length() == 0){
        model.addAttribute("personToEditOrCreate", new Person());
    }
    else{
        Person p = personService.getPersonByFirstName(fname);
        model.addAttribute("personToEditOrCreate", p);
    }

    return "persons/edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePerson(Person person, BindingResult result) {

    personService.savePerson(person);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

edit.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="personToEditOrCreate" action="save">
    <form:hidden path="id"/> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="money">Money</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="money" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Add/Edit Person"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

</form:form>
```

Im trying the code above (without using the @ModelAttribute annotation in the savePerson method, and it works correct. Why and when do i need to add the annotation to the person object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePerson(@ModelAttribute("personToEditOrCreate") Person person, BindingResult result) {

    personService.savePerson(person);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You don't need `@ModelAttribute` (**parameter**) just to use a Bean as a parameter

For example, these handler methods work fine with these requests:

```
@RequestMapping("/a")
void pathA(SomeBean someBean) {
  assertEquals("neil", someBean.getName());
}

GET /a?name=neil

@RequestMapping(value="/a", method=RequestMethod.POST)
void pathAPost(SomeBean someBean) {
  assertEquals("neil", someBean.getName());
}

POST /a
name=neil
```

---

Use `@ModelAttribute` (**method**) to load **default data** into your model on every request - for example from a database, especially when using `@SessionAttributes`. This can be done in a `Controller` or in a `ControllerAdvice`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foos")
public class FooController {

  @ModelAttribute("foo")
  String getFoo() {
    return "bar";  // set modelMap["foo"] = "bar" on every request
  }

}
```

Any JSP forwarded to by `FooController`:

```
${foo} //=bar
```

or

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyGlobalData {

  @ModelAttribute("foo")
  String getFoo() {
    return "bar";  // set modelMap["foo"] = "bar" on every request
  }

}
```

Any JSP:

```
${foo} //=bar
```

---

Use `@ModelAttribute` (**parameter**) if you want to use the result of `@ModelAttribute` (**method**) as a *default*:

```
@ModelAttribute("attrib1")
SomeBean getSomeBean() {
  return new SomeBean("neil");  // set modelMap["attrib1"] = SomeBean("neil") on every request
}

@RequestMapping("/a")
void pathA(@ModelAttribute("attrib1") SomeBean someBean) {
  assertEquals("neil", someBean.getName());
}

GET /a
```

---

Use `@ModelAttribute` (**parameter**) to get an object stored in a **flash attribute**:

```
@RequestMapping("/a")
String pathA(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("attrib1", new SomeBean("from flash"));
  return "redirect:/b";
}

@RequestMapping("/b")
void pathB(@ModelAttribute("attrib1") SomeBean someBean) {
  assertEquals("from flash", someBean.getName());
}

GET /a
```

---

Use `@ModelAttribute` (**parameter**) to get an object stored by `@SessionAttributes`

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("attrib1")
public class Controller1 {

    @RequestMapping("/a")
    void pathA(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("attrib1", new SomeBean("neil")); //this ends up in session due to @SessionAttributes on controller
    }

    @RequestMapping("/b")
    void pathB(@ModelAttribute("attrib1") SomeBean someBean) {
        assertEquals("neil", someBean.getName());
    }
}

GET /a
GET /b
```

---

Comment: How to use `@ModelAttribute` in `PUT` method

Comment: Just Wow. So useful

Comment: How would you set default values for @ModelAttribute when using it as a  parameter? Ex: (@RequestParam(value = "studentName", defaultValue="Alexa")

Comment: the part that ModelAttribute being used to get a model passes by RedirectAttribute is very enlightening. thanks

Comment: I frankly think, that the `@ModelAttribute` is one of the most vaguely named, unintuitively described and poorly documented annotation. It brings so much ambiguity, confusion and head-scratching, to so many people..

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I agree. They should at least split it to `@SetModelAttribute` and `@GetModelAttribute` or similar

Answer (score 3):

Your question appears to be answered already:

[What is @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc)

To summarize the answer and blog post: when you want your form backing object (instance of Person) to be persisted across requests.

Otherwise, without the annotation, the request mapped method will assume Person is a new object and in no way linked to your form backing object. The blog post that poster references is really awesome by the way, definitely a must-read.

Comment: ...but values in Model are not persisted across requests unless you are using RedirectAttributesModelMap? init?

Answer (score 0):

An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument will be retrieved from the model.If not present in the model, the argument will be instantiated first and then added to the model.