# Spring model attribute declaration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model, spring-boot, modelattribute

What is the difference between declaring `@ModelAttribute` as a method parameter and using `model.asMap()`?

Example:

```
public void method1(@ModelAttribute("attr") MyObject myObj) {
...
}

public void method2(Model model) {
    MyObject myObj = (MyObject) model.asMap().get("attr");
}
```

These are not the same if that's what your thinking. I tried to get an attribute from the model doing it the first way but didn't work so ended up doing it the second way.

Thanks

EDIT: What I mean by "it didn't work" is that when I used `@ModelAttribute`, it was confusing the values of the variables in that object to another object of a different type which had the same variable names.

EDIT #2: No it is not a duplicate because he does not address the model.asMap() method. As per the other post, I tried using @ModelAttribute on a @SessionAttributes variable but ran into problems so had to use model.asMap()

Comment: possible duplicate of [@ModelAttribute annotation, when to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688135/modelattribute-annotation-when-to-use-it)