# Supporting application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded simultaneously from Spring's rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

Am writing a REST endpoint which needs to support both application/x-www-form-urlencoded and application/json as request body simultaneously. I have made below configuration,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = {          
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, path = Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_V1_ENDPOINT)
public OAuth2Authorization createAccessTokenPost(
        @RequestBody(required = false) MultiValueMap<String, String> paramMap) { ..
```

While it supports application/x-www-form-urlencoded or application/json individually (when I comment out one content type from consumes = {}), but it does not support both simultaneously. Any ideas ?

Comment: What exception you see in the logs?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying.

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:237)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.

Comment: What values does Accept & Content-Type request header carry respectively?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Please check following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462450/spring-binding-object-with-and-without-modelattribute

Answer (score 5):

So RestControllers by default can handle `application/json` fairly easily and can create a request pojo from a `@RequestBody` annotated parameter, while `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` takes a little more work. A solution could be creating an extra RestController method that has the same mapping endpoint to handle the different kinds of requests that come in (`application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, etc). This is because `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` endpoints need to use the `@RequestParam` instead of the `@RequestBody` annotation (for `application/json`).

For instance if I wanted to host a POST endpoint for `/emp` that takes either `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as Content-Types and uses a service to do something, I could create Overload methods like so

```
@Autowired
private EmpService empService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/emp", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity createEmp(final @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = false) String authorizationHeader,
                                final @RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {
        //After receiving a FORM URLENCODED request, change it to your desired request pojo with ObjectMapper
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final TokenRequest tokenRequest = mapper.convertValue(map, CreateEmpRequest.class);
        return empService.create(authorizationHeader, createEmpRequest);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/emp", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity createEmp(final @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = false) String authorizationHeader,
                                final @RequestBody CreateEmpRequest createEmpRequest) {
        //Receieved a JSON request, the @RequestBody Annotation can handle turning the body of the request into a request pojo without extra lines of code
        return empService.create(authorizationHeader, createEmpRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my findings, spring does not support content types "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`", "`application/json`" and "`application/xml`" together.

**Reason I figured**: Spring processes JSON and XML types by parsing and injecting them into the java pojo marked with `@RequestBody` spring annotation. However, `x-www-form-urlencoded` must be injected into a `MultiValueMap<>` object marked with `@RequestBody`. Two different java types marked with `@RequestBody` will not be supported simultaneously, as spring may not know where to inject the payload.

**A working solution**:

"`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`" can be supported as it is in the API. That is, it can be injected into spring's `MultiValueMap<>` using an @RequestBody annotation.

To support JSON and XML on the same method, we can leverage servlet specification and spring's class built on top of them to extract the payload as stream.

**Sample code**:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

// usual REST service class

@Autowired
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

@Autowired
private Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter;

public ResponseEntity<Object> authorizationRequestPost(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody(required = false) MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters) {

    // this MultiValueMap<String,String> will contain key value pairs of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" parameters.

    // payload object to be populated
    Authorization authorization = null;

    HttpInputMessage inputMessage = new ServletServerHttpRequest(request) {
                    @Override
                    public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
                        return request.getInputStream();
                    }
                };

    if (request.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) {
        authorization = (Authorization) mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(Authorization.class, inputMessage);
    } 
    else if (request.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)) {
        authorization = (Authorization)jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.read(Authorization.class, inputMessage);
    }
    else{
        // extract values from MultiValueMap<String,String> and populate Authorization
    }

// remaining method instructions
}
```

**Point to note** that any custom data type/markup/format can be supported using this approach. Spring's `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter<>` can be extended to write the parsing logic.

**Another possible approach** could be an AOP style solution which would execute the same logic: parse payload by extracting it from `HttpServlet` input stream and inject into the payload object.

**A third approach** will be to write a filter for executing the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it, the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50873266/8459761) doesn't work as even if you do not annotate `MultiValueMap` with `@RequestBody` it would always check for `contentType==MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE` which again in rest of the cases resolves to `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to handle `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests simultaneously with a single Spring controller method.

Spring get `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data by [ServletRequest.getParameter(java.lang.String)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)), the document said:

> For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.
>
> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of this method.

So, if your method parameter is annotated with `@RequestBody`, Spring will read request body and parse it to the method parameter object. But `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` leads Spring to populate the parameter object by invoking [ServletRequest.getParameter(java.lang.String)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)).