# RestController with multiple consumes ( application/x-www-form-urlencoded and application/json )

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

SpringBoot 2.6.7

The annotation `@PostMapping` allows multiple values for the `consumes` attribute to specify different media types / content-types, but it seems that it is impossible to implement a single method that actually allows multiple content/media types.

In the sample code below, separate methods `enroll1` and `enroll2` uses the same POJO class to capture the request ( `Ping` class in the sample below ) from either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`, respectively.

Note that the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is also mapped to a POJO, unlike similar questions in stackoverflow where they are mapped to a `java.util.Map`.

NOTE: Yes, I looked at [Supporting application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded simultaneously from Spring's rest controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924463/supporting-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-simultaneously) ... but that one uses `MultiValueMap` for the parameter while I am using a POJO for both media types.

```
package org.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class SampleController {

//    @PostMapping(value = "ping", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
//    public @ResponseBody Pong enroll(@Valid @ModelAttribute @RequestBody Ping ping) {
//        Pong pong = new Pong();
//        pong.setEcho(ping.getText());
//        pong.setSuccess(true);
//        return pong;
//    }

    @PostMapping(value = "ping", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody Pong enroll1(@Valid Ping ping) {
        return doBoth(ping);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "ping", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody Pong enroll2(@Valid @RequestBody Ping ping) {
        return doBoth(ping);
    }

    private Pong doBoth(Ping ping) {
        Pong pong = new Pong();
        pong.setEcho(ping.getText());
        pong.setSuccess(true);
        return pong;
    }
}
```

Notice that the method method accepting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not need to have the `@ModelAttribute` annotation on the `ping` parameter.

```
package org.example.demo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Ping {

    @NotNull
    private String text;
}
```

```
package org.example.demo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Pong {
    private String echo;
    private boolean success;
}
```

While the above works OK, what I would have wanted is for that commented out code to work ( and commenting out / removing the other two methods `enroll1()` and `enroll2()` above ):

```
    @PostMapping(value = "ping", consumes = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody Pong enroll(@Valid @ModelAttribute @RequestBody Ping ping) {
        Pong pong = new Pong();
        pong.setEcho(ping.getText());
        pong.setSuccess(true);
        return pong;
    }
```

In real life, this method and others similar like it have other annotations ( like Swagger / OpenAPI plus other custom annotations ) that would be best to have in just one method instead of being repeated in two methods.

But you cannot annotate the method parameter with both `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` at the same time. If you do, you get :

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/test/ping -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d text=Hello
{"echo":"Hello","success":true}
$
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/test/ping -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"text":"Hello"}'
{"timestamp":1651307540135,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/test/ping"}
```

You get the above results as well ( only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works ) if you:

- Remove the `@RequestBody` annotation but keep the `@ModelAttribute` annotation, OR
- Remove both `@RequestBody` and `@ModelAttribute` annotations.

If you remove the `@ModelAttribute` annotation and leave the `@RequestBody` annotation on the parameter, you get the results reversed ( but get an HTTP 415 instead of an HTTP 400 ) .The log says `Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported`:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "ping", consumes = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody Pong enroll(@Valid @RequestBody Ping ping) {
        Pong pong = new Pong();
        pong.setEcho(ping.getText());
        pong.setSuccess(true);
        return pong;
```

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/test/ping -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d text=Hello
{"timestamp":1651307931120,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/test/ping"}
$ 
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/test/ping -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"text":"Hello"}'
{"echo":"Hello","success":true}
```

Does anyone have a working implementation where a single method have multiple values for the `consumes` attribute of the `@PostMapping` annotation, where the request is mapped to a POJO ?

I would like to think that there are, otherwise, it would make no sense to allow it as an array.