# Spring Form Tag: How does the form tag bind values to your DTO?

Tags: forms, spring, dto, taglib, inject

Sample form:

```
<form:form commandName="loginDTO" action="/login">
<form:input path="username"/>
<form:input path="password"/>
</form:form>
```

Sample Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String loginUser(LoginDTO loginDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel){
    //some code
}
```

I want to know how Spring does the automatic injection to the specified LoginDTO. Does Spring access the setter methods?

Comment: Read about `@ModelAttribute` [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc) and [in this post](http://bearprogrammer.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/what-is-and-how-to-use-modelattribute/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Spring uses setter methods for data binding, but you can configure it to use direct field access instead, by calling `DataBinder.initDirectFieldAccess()` when configuring a `DataBinder`:

```
@InitBinder
public void configureBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.initDirectFieldAccess();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The Spring API is ridiculously overwhelming for beginners like me.