# org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, spring-annotations

I am doing CRUD using spring jdbc template.
insert,select and delete operations are working fine but I got these following exception in update process.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.Integer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()
```

here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editCompany/{companyId}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@PathVariable(value="companyId")Integer companyId,ModelMap map) {

        Company company=companyService.get(companyId);
        map.addAttribute("company", company);
        map.put("companyId", companyId);
        return "editCompany"; 
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/editCompany/{companyId}", method= RequestMethod.POST)
        public String save(@ModelAttribute("company")Integer companyId,Company company,BindingResult result, ModelMap map) {

        companyValidator.validate(company, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "editCompany";
        } else {
            Integer i=companyService.save(company);

            return "status";
        }
    }
```

I have used `@Autowired` annotation for the controller too.
How to resolve it? any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my Post method to following and it worked.

```
public String save(@ModelAttribute("company")Company company,BindingResult result, ModelMap map)
```

Comment: It works because that you changed your ModelAttribute to a Company object. However, I would recommend reading some more to understand the basics of ModelAttribute (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc). In short, if you only need this attribute in one request, then using ModelAttribute is a waste.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you are trying to use an Integer companyId as a ModelAttribute. I won't recommend ModelAttribute for this case (since it's overkill & easy to misuse), but in case you use, have you declare the value of that ModelAttribute before?

```
public String save(@ModelAttribute("company")Integer companyId,Company company,BindingResult result, ModelMap map) {
```

If you only specify the value like above, **the system will try to initialize an Integer for all the requests**. This can't be complete because class Integer doesn't have a default instructor.

Hence I recommend doing it like this:

```
public String save(@RequestParam("company")Integer companyId,Company company,BindingResult result, ModelMap map) {
```

If you still want to use a shared ModelAttribute for all your request, you must intialize it first:

```
@ModelAttribute("company")
public Integer companyId(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but using @Valid it's giving an error "The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Valid"

Comment: sorry, I forgot. @Valid is only used for Object. Anyway, you won't need to validate an Integer. "@RequestParam" is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ModelAttribute("company")
public Integer companyId(){
return 0;
}
```

beware with this, you will have 0 in all companyId and this could be dangerous for crud.

¿can you use?

```
@PathVariable(value="companyId")
```

edit must be like save the only change is the companyId if you are saving must be 0 or null and if you are editing must be the id of the company

Answer (score -3):

Your URL cannot be repeated differently.

1. you must be sure of the URL
2. `@ModelAttribute ("company") company`