# Wildfly 11 - Java Spring application - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, noclassdeffounderror

In my Java application I'm using Spring 4.0.3.
It starts without any Exceptions or Errors.

When I invoke a Rest- Service of my application to store something in my database I get the following stacktrace:

```
09:19:13,056 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-10) UT005023: Exception handling request to /myapp/messages/myTemplate/cb5dc950-db86-11e5-90bc-168020524153: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/eaio/uuid/UUID
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1276)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
```

The Error appears at this line of code:

```
final MessageTemplateNotGroup contactMessageTemplateNotGroup = this.saveOrUpdate(messageTemplateNotGroup);
```

This is how the mehtod saveOrUpdate is defined:

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
public T saveOrUpdate(final T entity) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    return entity;

}
```

In my application pom I have defined the uuid artefact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.eaio.uuid</groupId>
    <artifactId>uuid</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I dont know why the uuid artefact is not be find and why I get the **NoClassDefFoundError**?

[image: jars in war file]

Comment: If you try mvn dependency:tree on the command line do you see the dependency `com.eaio.uuid` in the output?

Comment: Take look into the war, if the library is in the WEB-INF/lib Directory. If not post the complete pom and give more Details about the Project structure.

Comment: [INFO] +- com.eaio.uuid:uuid:jar:3.2:compile is in the dependency tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using @ModelAttribute `/myapp/messages/myTemplate/{xyz}` request, then change this to @RequestParam.

or

Try to use WildFly - 8.2 or use Jboss 7, because this is an issue with WildFly - 11 and WildFly - 8.1.

If not solved then send me request method you call.

Comment: take [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332982/org-springframework-web-util-nestedservletexception-request-processing-failed) reference