# Spring MVC: bind request attribute to controller method parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, it is easy to bind request *parameter* to method paramaters handling the request. I just use `@RequestParameter("name")`. But can I do the same with request *attribute*? Currently, when I want to access request *attribute*, I have to do following:

```
MyClass obj = (MyClass) request.getAttribute("attr_name");
```

But I really would like to use something like this instead:

```
@RequestAttribute("attr_name") MyClass obj
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way. Can I somehow extend Spring functionality and add my own "binders"?

**EDIT** *(what I'm trying to achieve)*: I store currently logged user inside request attribute. So whenever I want to access currently logged user (which is pretty much inside every method), I have to write this extra line `user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");`. I would like to make it as short as possible, preferably inject it as a method parameter. Or if you know another way how to pass something across interceptors and controllers, I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, I finally understood a little bit how models work and what is `@ModelAttribute` for. Here is my solution.

```
@Controller 
class MyController
{
    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User getUser(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        return (User) request.getAttribute("user");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "someurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String HandleSomeUrl(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)  
    {
        // ... do some stuff
    }
}
```

The `getUser()` method marked with `@ModelAttribute` annotation will automatically populate all `User user` parameters marked with `@ModelAttribute`. So when the HandleSomeUrl method is called, the call looks something like `MyController.HandleSomeUrl(MyController.getUser(request))`. At least this is how I imagine it. Cool thing is that user is also accessible from the JSP view without any further effort.

This solves exactly my problem however I do have further questions. Is there a common place where I can put those `@ModelAttribute` methods so they were common for all my controllers? Can I somehow add model attribute from the inside of the `preHandle()` method of an Interceptor?

Comment: If your parameter names match properties on your model object, you dont need the additional getUser method, spring will set those properties automatically

Comment: In this way the User object in your method will not only be retrieved from the view model, but also its properties will be bound (and overwritten) by incoming request- or form parameters.  If, for example, the User object has an id property (which many user objects will have) and the request url or form also have a unrelated) id parameter, it will overwrite the id of the User object. This has once created a nasty bug in my code. In this particular case, you do not want the form binding properties of the @ModelAttribute. An alternative is using `User u = (User) model.get("user");`

Answer (score 14):

Use (as of Spring 4.3) [@RequestAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestAttribute.html):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "someurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleSomeUrl(@RequestAttribute User user) {
    // ... do some stuff
}
```

or if the request attribute name does not match the method parameter name:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "someurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleSomeUrl(@RequestAttribute(name="userAttributeName") User user) {
    // ... do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
@ModelAttribute("attr_name") MyClass obj
```

You can use that in the parameters for a method in your controller.

Here is a link a to question with details on it [What is @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc)

That question links to the Spring Documentation with some examples of using it too.  You can see that [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)

**Update**

I'm not sure how you are setting up your pages, but you can add the user as a Model Attribute a couple different ways.  I setup a simple example below here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayAccountPage() {
    User user = new User(); //most likely you've done some kind of login step this is just for simplicity
    return new ModelAndView("account", "user", user); //return view, model attribute name, model attribute
}
```

Then when the user submits a request, Spring will bind the user attribute to the User object in the method parameters.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/delivery", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateDeliverySchedule(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {

    user = accountService.updateDeliverySchedule(user); //do something with the user

    return new ModelAndView("account", "user", user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to achieve something else.. maybe I should have explained that. I use request attribute to store currently logged user. So just as you call `User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");` I call `user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");`. But it's quite annoying to write that in every single method. I would like to make this as short as possible, preferably inject it as the method parameter.

Comment: You can still use this method to do that.  You just need to add the User object to the model.  Then you can access it.  There are a couple ways to do that.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am not as familiar with `@SessionAttributes` but that might work for you too.  Here is a [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib) to the documentation on it.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if I understand you but you definitely put me in the right direction and I found what I've been looking for. So thanks and see my own answer in few moments :)

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant, but works at least...

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @RequestMapping("/xyz")
    public ModelAndView handle(
        @Value("#{request.getAttribute('key')}") SomeClass obj) {

        ...
        return new ModelAndView(...);
    }

}
```

Source : http://blog.crisp.se/tag/requestattribute

Answer (score 1):

From spring 3.2 it can be done even nicer by using Springs [ControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation.
This then would allow you to have an advice which adds the @ModelAttributes in a separate class, which is then applied to all your controllers.

For completeness, it is also possible to actually make the @RequestAttribute("attr-name") as is.
(below modified from [this article](https://sergialmar.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/extending-handler-method-argument-resolution-in-spring-mvc/) to suit our demands)

First, we have to define the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface RequestAttribute {
    String value();
}
```

Then we need a [WebArgumentResolver] to handle what needs to be done when the attribute is being bound

```
public class RequestAttributeWebArgumentResolver implements WebArgumentResolver {

    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest) throws Exception {
        // Get the annotation       
        RequestAttribute requestAttributeAnnotation = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(RequestAttribute.class);

        if(requestAttributeAnnotation != null) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest();

            return request.getAttribute(requestAttributeAnnotation.value);
        }

        return UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
```

Now all we need is to add this customresolver to the config to resolve it:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="customArgumentResolver">
        <bean class="com.sergialmar.customresolver.web.support.CustomWebArgumentResolver"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And we're done!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add your own 'binders' to the request attribute - see [spring-mvc-3-showcase](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/), or use @Peter Szanto's solution.

Alternatively, bind it as a ModelAttribute, as recommended in other answers.

As it's the logged-in user that you want to pass into your controller, you may want to consider [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). Then you can just have the [Principle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) injected into your method:

```
@RequestMapping("/xyz")
public String index(Principal principle) {
    return "Hello, " + principle.getName() + "!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring WebMVC 4.x, it prefer implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

```
@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(RequestAttribute.class) != null;
}

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    return webRequest.getAttribute(parameter.getParameterAnnotation(RequestAttribute.class).value(), NativeWebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
}
```

}

Then register it in RequestMappingHandlerAdapter