# @ModelAttribute always maps Boolean to false

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, modelattribute

when I try to map Boolean value from url to spring controller, it always map to false.

This is my url

```
http://localhost:8080/myurl?isFirstTime=true
```

here is my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<?>  getMyUrl(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyObject ap,BindingResult bindingResult ) {

//here isFirstTime is always set to false

}
```

`MyObj` is POJO and has several other attributes which are mapping perfectly

```
public class Myobj{

 private boolean isFirstTime
  //there are other members as well
    //getter setter
```

i tried putting `@JsonProperty` but that also didn't work

```
@JsonProperty
private boolean isFirstTime
```

any idea what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: you should use `POST` request instead of `GET` or use `@RequestParam boolean isFirstTime`

Comment: so you are saying this is not possible using get

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032063/spring-mvc-bind-request-attribute-to-controller-method-parameter)

Comment: i don't get any clue from that link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

With @ModelAttribute, the object will be initialized:

- From the model if already added via Model.
- From the HTTP session via @SessionAttributes.
- From a URI path variable passed through a Converter.
- From the invocation of a default constructor.
- From the invocation of a "primary constructor" with arguments matching to Servlet request parameters; argument names are determined via JavaBeans

In your case, it might relative to the last statement.

You can try 2 way to solve it:
- Provide the constructor with the boolean argument in Myobj.java
- Add more method to initialize the @ModelAttribute Myobj firstly

```
@ModelAttribute
public Myobj initObj(@RequestMapping boolean isFirstTime){
     Myobj obj = new MyObj();
     obj.setIsFirstTime(isFirstTime);
     return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest method could be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?>  getMyUrl(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyObject ap,@RequestParam boolean isFirstTime, BindingResult bindingResult ) {
```

//here isFirstTime is always initialized from incoming request parameters
// you can set it ap.isFirstTime(isFirstTime); // or whatever your setter method is

}

Answer (score 0):

I stuck at this problem, but I've found that we must use Boolean object instead of boolean primitive type to map boolean value correctly in ModelAttribute

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).