# Spring MVC keep value of unexposed property model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a **Model** class:

```
public class User{
    public String title;
    public String username;

    /* setter getter here */

    public String toString(){
        /* output title and username */
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping("/dummy")
public class DummyController
{
    private log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @RequestMapping(value="binder")
    public String binderInput(Model model){ 
        UserLogin userInit=UserLogin.findUserLogin(1L);
        model.addAttribute("userLogin",userInit);               
        return "binderInput";   
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="binderResult")
    public String binderResult(@ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin,BindingResult br){
        log.debug("userLogin:"+userLogin);
        return "binderResult";  
    }
}
```

And **views** (jspx) for binderInput:

```
<form:form action="dummy/binderResult" method="POST" modelAttribute="userLogin">
    title:<form:input path="title" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

The DAO in 
`UserLogin.findUserLogin(1L);`
will return user with title '**Mr**' and username '**Smith**'.
I browse `localhost:8080/myWeb/dummy` and the views showed 'Mr' in title field, and then i update the title to '**Sir**' and submit the form.

In binderResult i expect to see

```
title:Sir, username:Smith
```

but actually i got

```
title:Sir, username:null
```

Is there a way to keep the property value(s) from the DAO that not edited (for the field(s) not showed in the jspx view) ?

1. I think of hidden field, but the username can be viewed when looking at html source and it can be manipulated so i think its cant be the solution.
2. I have tried `@SessionAttribute`, i thought it is make sense the model is keeped in the session and then spring `modelAttribute` will only fill the properties that received from the views to the session model. But then it still the same, title change to Sir but the username is null.
3. I read about `@InitBinder` and try 
    `dataBinder.setAllowedFields(new String[]{"title"});`
   but its not help, it just filters the properties and  not keep the value of the other *not allowed* fields

I start to think that i have to do it manually something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="binderResult")
    public String binderResult(@ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin,BindingResult br,HttpSession session){
        /* after put DAO model in session in binderInput */
        UserLogin userLoginSession = session.getAttribute("userLoginSession");
        userLoginSession.setUsername(userLogin.getUsername());
                    //further process or save userLoginSession
        log.debug("userLogin:"+userLoginSession);
        return "dummy/binderResult";    
    }
```

Is there a way to keep the not edited property in Spring like what i expect in the first place?

Thanks for any help!

=====================================================

Code for my 2nd point, asked by gouki:

```
@RequestMapping("/dummy")
@SessionAttributes({"userSession"})
public class Dummy2Controller
{
    private log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @RequestMapping(value="binder")
    public String binderInput(Model model,HttpSession session){ 
        UserLogin userInit=UserLogin.findUserLogin(1L);
        model.addAttribute("userSession",userInit);             
        return "binderInput";   
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="binderResult")
    public String binderResult(@ModelAttribute UserLogin userSession,BindingResult br,HttpSession session){
        log.debug("userSession:"+userSession);
        //further process or save userSession to DB
        return "binderResult";  
    }
}
```

and change modelAttribute to **userSession** in views:

`<form:form action="dummy/binderResult" method="POST" modelAttribute="userSession">`

=====================================================
**PROBLEM SOLVED**
Some link that i read related to accepted answer in this question:

1. [springsource docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)
2. [stackoverflow explanation by @Christopher Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc)
3. [Captain Debug's Blog](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/11/using-spring-mvcs-modelattribute.html)

Comment: please show code of your 2nd solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add method, which will populate object before invocation of every controller method:

```
@ModelAttribute("userLogin")
public UserLogin getUserLogin() {
    return UserLogin.findUserLogin(1L);
}
```

After this loading changed fields from submitted form will override old values and in your controller you'll have refreshed object.

Comment: Thanks that works! just dont forget to make sure you have **BindingResult** right after your modelAttribute parameter or else it doesnt work(CMIIW). I will update the question to add some link that might be help about this called **ModelAttribute on a Method**.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your problem, and I would probably uses Max's approach first, but you can use Spring Webflow and it's conversation context to keep a copy of the object around:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html

Search for conversationScope, they don't provide a link directly to it.