# Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Suppose i have a page that lists the objects on a table and i need to put a form to filter the table. The filter is sent as an Ajax GET to an URL like that: http://foo.com/system/controller/action?page=1&prop1=x&prop2=y&prop3=z

And instead of having lots of parameters on my Controller like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public @ResponseBody List<MyObject> myAction(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
    @RequestParam(value = "prop1", required = false) String prop1,
    @RequestParam(value = "prop2", required = false) String prop2,
    @RequestParam(value = "prop3", required = false) String prop3) { ... }
```

And supposing i have MyObject as:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    private String prop3;

    //Getters and setters
    ...
}
```

I wanna do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public @ResponseBody List<MyObject> myAction(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
    @RequestParam(value = "myObject", required = false) MyObject myObject,) { ... }
```

Is it possible? 
How can i do that?

Comment: @michal +1. Here is a couple of tutorials showing how to do that: [Spring 3 MVC: Handling Forms in Spring 3.0 MVC](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/), [What is and how to use `@ModelAttribute`](http://bearprogrammer.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/what-is-and-how-to-use-modelattribute/), [Spring MVC Form Handling Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm). Just google "*Spring MVC form handling*" and you'll get a ton of tutorials/examples. But be sure to use modern way of form handling, i.e. Spring v2.5+

Comment: Also useful: [What is `@ModelAttribute` in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3423501/814702)

Comment: remove @RequestParam from the MyObject and also make attributes of the MyObject definable (by adding a no-arg constructor and setter for all the attributes) or (define an all-args constructor without no-args constructor, the setter is not needed in this case).

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You can absolutely do that, just remove the `@RequestParam` annotation, Spring will cleanly bind your request parameters to your class instance:

```
public @ResponseBody List<MyObject> myAction(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
    MyObject myObject)
```

Comment: Note that Spring by default requiers getters/setters for the MyObject to bind it automatically. Otherway it won't bind the myObject.

Comment: How can you set fields are optional/non-optional in MyObject? Not sure how to find proper documentation for this..

Comment: Works perfectly. Do you have a link to the documentation, specifically if  I can combine it with @Valid?

Comment: @Biju, Is there a way to control default values and required for `MyObject` then, in a similar way we can do with @RequestParam?

Comment: Yes @Alexey, you can do this via `@ModelAttribute` - if you have a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method you can provide the default values there and then your real method can add in other details from the request  - here is a link with more information on how to do this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

Comment: this solutions works with objects, but dont work with Lists. 
I'm trying to get a List of MyObject. Any idea?

Comment: @BijuKunjummen How can I update the `MyObject` to accept query parameters in Snake case and map it to a camel case member of `MyObject`. For example, `?book_id=4`, should be mapped with `bookId` member of the `MyObject`?

Comment: @worldsayshi I suppose, since Java 8, you could use Optional fields for this.

Comment: If there is also an `@RequestParam` in the method parameters then the only way I could get this to work was by adding `@ModelAttribute`, if no `@RequestParam` are present, then using a plain object without annotation also worked.

Comment: @worldsayshi If I got you right, you can validate body with `@Valid` & standard validation annotations

Comment: I have request params as such: `page-number` and `page-size`. How will my request DTO object look like? In java, I can't create a field with the name `page-number` or `page-size`. Is there a way to tell spring that the request param with the given name should be mapped to this or that field? Please advise.

Comment: To add on [aka_sh(]https://stackoverflow.com/users/271146/aka-sh) comment. You can still make it work with Jackson Annotation, or Mixins. `class MyObject {
    public final String prop1;
@JsonCreator MyObject(@JsonProperty("prop1") String prop1){}
}`. Then you don't need gettter/settters.

Comment: How can I define a LocalDateTime filter in my dto?

Comment: @@worldsayshi for that you have to add all the required parameters along with this method.....like in this example MyObject have two parameters "page" and "anotherparam" , now you can set required to true or false
public @ResponseBody List<MyObject> myAction(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
    @RequestParam(value = "anotherparam", required = true) String something,
    MyObject myObject)

Comment: how do you call the API ? I used exchange but it didnt work. how do you put the object as a parameter ?

Comment: One can use `@BindParam("custom-param-name")` annotation to explicitly set the name for the parameter.

Answer (score 70):

I will add some short example from me.

The DTO class:

```
public class SearchDTO {
    private Long id[];

    public Long[] getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long[] id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // reflection toString from apache commons
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }
}
```

Request mapping inside controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/handle", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String handleRequest(SearchDTO search) {
    LOG.info("criteria: {}", search);
    return "OK";
}
```

Query:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/handle?id=353,234
```

Result:

```
[http-apr-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.g.g.r.f.w.ExampleController.handleRequest:59 - criteria: SearchDTO[id={353,234}]
```

I hope it helps :)

**UPDATE / KOTLIN**

Because currently I'm working a lot of with Kotlin if someone wants to define similar DTO the class in Kotlin should have the following form:

```
class SearchDTO {
    var id: Array<Long>? = arrayOf()

    override fun toString(): String {
        // to string implementation
    }
}
```

With the `data` class like this one:

```
data class SearchDTO(var id: Array<Long> = arrayOf())
```

the Spring (tested in Boot) returns the following error for request mentioned in answer:

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type
>   'java.lang.Long[]'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"353,234\""

The data class will work only for the following request params form:

```
http://localhost:8080/handle?id=353&id=234
```

Be aware of this!

Comment: is it possible to set "required" to dto fields?

Comment: I suggest to try with Spring MVC validators. Example: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api

Comment: It's very curious that this does not require an annotation! I wonder, is there an explicit annotation for this albeit unnecessary?

Comment: This behavior difference with java/kotlin should be an error. I created an issue. Spend few hours to search why it was not working but I used to have no problem in java. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25815

Comment: Thanks for Kotlin way, but there is any way to immutable object and use val instead var to work ?

Answer (score 12):

Since the question on how to set fields mandatory pops up under each post, I wrote a small example on how to set fields as required:

```
public class ExampleDTO {
    @NotNull
    private String mandatoryParam;

    private String optionalParam;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) //accept Dates only in YYYY-MM-DD
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate testDate;

    public String getMandatoryParam() {
        return mandatoryParam;
    }
    public void setMandatoryParam(String mandatoryParam) {
        this.mandatoryParam = mandatoryParam;
    }
    public String getOptionalParam() {
        return optionalParam;
    }
    public void setOptionalParam(String optionalParam) {
        this.optionalParam = optionalParam;
    }
    public LocalDate getTestDate() {
        return testDate;
    }
    public void setTestDate(LocalDate testDate) {
        this.testDate = testDate;
    }
}

//Add this to your rest controller class
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testComplexObject (@Valid ExampleDTO e){
    System.out.println(e.getMandatoryParam() + " " + e.getTestDate());
    return "Does this work?";
}
```

Comment: Doest that work today? Tried here, but the validations that I set on the pojo didnt work.

Comment: Yes it still works. Maybe this question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436804/spring-valid-doesnt-work

If you need more assistance I need some example code to look at it further.

Answer (score 7):

I have a very similar problem. Actually the problem is deeper as I thought. I am using jquery `$.post` which uses `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` as default. Unfortunately I based my system on that and when I needed a complex object as a `@RequestParam` I couldn't just make it happen.

In my case I am trying to send user preferences with something like;

```
 $.post("/updatePreferences",  
    {id: 'pr', preferences: p}, 
    function (response) {
 ...
```

On client side the actual raw data sent to the server is;

```
...
id=pr&preferences%5BuserId%5D=1005012365&preferences%5Baudio%5D=false&preferences%5Btooltip%5D=true&preferences%5Blanguage%5D=en
...
```

parsed as;

```
id:pr
preferences[userId]:1005012365
preferences[audio]:false
preferences[tooltip]:true
preferences[language]:en
```

and the server side is;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePreferences")
public
@ResponseBody
Object updatePreferences(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("preferences") UserPreferences preferences) {

    ...
        return someService.call(preferences);
    ...
}
```

I tried `@ModelAttribute`, added setter/getters, constructors with all possibilities to `UserPreferences` but no chance as it recognized the sent data as 5 parameters but in fact the mapped method has only 2 parameters. I also tried Biju's solution however what happens is that, spring creates an UserPreferences object with default constructor and doesn't fill in the data.

I solved the problem by sending JSon string of the preferences from the client side and handle it as if it is a String on the server side;

client:

```
 $.post("/updatePreferences",  
    {id: 'pr', preferences: JSON.stringify(p)}, 
    function (response) {
 ...
```

server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePreferences")
public
@ResponseBody
Object updatePreferences(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("preferences") String preferencesJSon) {


        String ret = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            UserPreferences userPreferences = mapper.readValue(preferencesJSon, UserPreferences.class);
            return someService.call(userPreferences);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

to brief, I did the conversion manually inside the REST method. In my opinion the reason why spring doesn't recognize the sent data is the content-type.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue too. I did cleaner workaround using `@RequestMapping(method = POST, path = "/settings/{projectId}")
    public void settings(@PathVariable String projectId, @RequestBody ProjectSettings settings)`

Comment: @Petr Újezdský your solution is not feasible because it completely changes the API (using request body instead of request parameter)

Answer (score 1):

While answers that refer to `@ModelAttribute`, `@RequestParam`, `@PathParam` and the likes are valid, there is a small gotcha I ran into. The resulting method parameter is a proxy that Spring wraps around your DTO. So, if you attempt to use it in a context that requires your own custom type, you may get some unexpected results.

The following will not work:

```
@GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<CustomDto> request(@ModelAttribute CustomDto dto) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(dto);
}
```

In my case, attempting to use it in Jackson binding resulted in a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException`.

You will need to create a new object from the dto.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it in a simple way. See below code of lines.

URL - **http://localhost:8080/get/request/multiple/param/by/map?name='abc' & id='123'**

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/get/request/header/by/map")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getRequestParamInMap(@RequestParam Map<String,String> map){
        // Do your business here 
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(map.toString(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works like a charm but if the object has a list of objects it won't work as expected so here is my solution after some digging.

Following [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/353086/what-is-a-proper-way-to-do-a-complex-restful-search-method/353105#353105?newreg=d5e6360ebf2b434da957a9faa10bffe0) advice, here is how I've done.

- Frontend: stringify your object than encode it in base64 for submission.
- Backend: decode base64 string then convert the string json into desired object.

It isn't the best for debugging your API with postman but it is working as expected for me.

> **Original object:** { page: 1, size: 5, filters: [{ field: "id", value: 1, comparison: "EQ" }
>
> **Encoded object:** eyJwYWdlIjoxLCJzaXplIjo1LCJmaWx0ZXJzIjpbeyJmaWVsZCI6ImlkUGFyZW50IiwiY29tcGFyaXNvbiI6Ik5VTEwifV19

```
@GetMapping
fun list(@RequestParam search: String?): ResponseEntity<ListDTO> {
    val filter: SearchFilterDTO = decodeSearchFieldDTO(search)
    ...
}

private fun decodeSearchFieldDTO(search: String?): SearchFilterDTO {
    if (search.isNullOrEmpty()) return SearchFilterDTO()
    return Gson().fromJson(String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(search)), SearchFilterDTO::class.java)
}
```

And here the SearchFilterDTO and FilterDTO

```
class SearchFilterDTO(
    var currentPage: Int = 1,
    var pageSize: Int = 10,
    var sort: Sort? = null,
    var column: String? = null,
    var filters: List<FilterDTO> = ArrayList<FilterDTO>(),
    var paged: Boolean = true
)

class FilterDTO(
    var field: String,
    var value: Any,
    var comparison: Comparison
)
```