# Spring map GET request parameters to POJO automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have method in my REST controller that contains a lot of parameters. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getItem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ServiceRequest<List<SomeModel>> getClaimStatuses(
        @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = true) List<String> param1,
        @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) String param2,
        @RequestParam(value = "param3", required = false) List<String> param3,
        @RequestParam(value = "param4", required = false) List<String> param4,
        @RequestParam(value = "param5", required = false) List<String> param5) {
    // ......
}
```

and I would like to map all GET request parameters to a POJO object like:

```
public class RequestParamsModel {

   public RequestParamsModel() {

   }

   public List<String> param1;
   public String param2;
   public List<String> param3;
   public String param4;
   public String param5;
}
```

I need something like we can do using @RequestBody in REST Controller.

**Is it possible to do in Spring 3.x ?**

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16942352/4074715

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Possible and easy, make sure that your bean has proper accessors for the fields. You can add proper validation per property, just make sure that you have the proper jars in place. In terms of code it would be something like

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class RequestParamsModel {

    public RequestParamsModel() {}

    private List<String> param1;
    private String param2;
    private List<String> param3;
    private String param4;
    private String param5;

    @NotNull
    public List<String> getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }
    //  ...
}
```

The controller method would be:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getItem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ServiceRequest<List<SomeModel>> getClaimStatuses(@Valid RequestParamsModel model) {
    // ...
}
```

And the request, something like:

```
/getItem?param1=list1,list2&param2=ok
```

Comment: What is the package for the NotNull annotation?

Comment: its `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`

Comment: Thread is probably dead but I got a question. How does the spring know to map the request params to the class, in this case, RequestParamsModel if we did not use @RequestParam annotation here?

Comment: @KalyanM Not sure, but I guess it works by convention

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getItem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ServiceRequest<List<SomeModel>> getClaimStatuses(@ModelAttribute RequestParamsModel requestParamModel) {
...
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have got empty requestParamModel. As I understood ModelAttribute is used for response model.

Comment: it works with ModelAttribute annotation and without, but RequestParamsModel must contain setter methods. Thanks!