# spring MVC request param auto mapping complex object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have seen similar answer here:

[Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam)

[Spring map GET request parameters to POJO automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612404/spring-map-get-request-parameters-to-pojo-automatically)

I really can't find document of this because this auto mapping is not even done by any annotation. (it doesn't even need `@RequestParam` in fact)

1) so far I only see simple mapping, the object contain all primitive data, how about if my request is a complicated JSON object which contain several level of attributes (a object contain other objects)? Will the auto-mapping still work?

2) so far I only see Spring controller can take in one auto-map object, can I let it auto-map more than one object? For example:

```
public @ResponseBody List<MyObject> myAction(MyObject myObject,
MyObject2 myObject2) { ... }
```

Anyone know where is the document to describe how the mapping work behind the scene? Based on my second question, if Spring allow to do such thing, what if I have same attributes name in `MyObject` and `MyObject2`, how the mapping will do?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. depends. There is a difference between marshaling JSON and mapping request parameters it is a HUGE difference. Basically all of this is explained in the Spring Reference Guide which I suggest you gave a read.

Comment: I supposed `RequestMapping` should be documented well in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html but I really can't find any clue.

Comment: I can't really understand this `There is a difference between marshaling JSON and mapping request parameters it is a HUGE difference` do you mind share a link? You can rely in answer below if it helps. thanks.

Comment: As I said there is a difference between binding (which relies on request parameters) and marshaling a request body. All of this, as mentioned earlier, is documented in the spring reference guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do things like this:

```
public @ResponseBody List<MyObject> myAction(@RequestBody MyObject myObject) { ... }
```

Of course you can only have one body in your http request.

As long as you have Jackson in your classpath (spring boot will add this automatically) your objects will be marshalled correctly.

If the JSON in your body is incorrect you will get a 400 (Invalid Request) returned.