# Spring MVC wrap a lot of @RequestParam to an Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a RESTful controller's method like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public
@ResponseBody
Object getAll(@RequestParam(value = "1", required = false) Integer a,
              @RequestParam(value = "2", required = false) Integer b,
              @RequestParam(value = "2", required = false) String c,
              @RequestParam(value = "3", required = false) String d,
              @RequestParam(value = "4", required = false) String e,
              @RequestParam(value = "5", required = false) String f,
              @RequestParam(value = "6", required = false) String g,
              @RequestParam(value = "7", required = false) String h,
              HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    //some logic
    return service.getAll();
}
```

Is it possible to wrap all parameters to some Data Transfer Object? To a class like:

```
     public class ParamsDTO {

public String a;

public String b;

public String c;

//list of all params
}
```

Thus I can refactor my controller's methods like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public
@ResponseBody
Object getAll(@RequestBody ParamsDTO params,
              HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    //some logic
    return service.getAll();
}
```

I'm asking because I have about 10 different URL mappings with all these params and if I'm going to add new or remove old one I have to change it in 10 places. Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam duplicate?

Comment: you should use a command object (or call it a dto), the only thing you neet to take care of is, that you have `String get1()` and `void set1(String value)` but your fields name must not be a single number, but `value1` for example.

Comment: Thanks hahn. It helps. Sorry for duplicate.