# how to bind incoming URI request to a custom RequestObject in Spring mvc 4

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4 on tomcat 8 with JDK 8.

Controller:

```
@RestController 
public class MyController {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/abc/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> myMethod(@PathVariable("id") String id,
            @RequestParam(value = "add", required = false, defaultValue = "1") String add,
            @RequestParam(value = "sub", required = false, defaultValue = "1") String sub,
            @RequestParam(value = "mul", required = false, defaultValue = "1") String mul,
            @RequestParam(value = "div", required = false, defaultValue = "1") String div) {

        MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
        request.setId(id);
        request.setAdd(add);
        request.setSub(sub);
        request.setMul(mul);
        request.setDiv(div);

        // call service implementation.. 
        service.myMethodImpl(request);
    }
```

So essentially, my URI looks like this: 
/abc/100?add=10&sub=10&mul=10&div=10

Are there any bindings/api/annotations available in SpringMVC so I don't have to bind MyRequest manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam)

Comment: @dustin.schultz thanks. should i delete my post if it is duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

No,

To process request we need those parameters only thing you can do is set them all as a POJO and then send as request parameter using post method then spring will automatically bind those values