# DTO has only null with GET request params, but not POST @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dto, http-request-parameters

I'm trying to get my query params in a DTO [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam) but my DTO has always null value.

Is there anything wrong in my code ? I made it as simple as possible.

**Queries**:

GET http://localhost:8080/api/test?a=azaz => null

POST http://localhost:8080/api/test with `{"a":"azaz"}` => "azaz"

**Controller with a GET and a POST**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = {"/api"}, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController {

    // GET: dto NOT populated from query params "?a=azaz"
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "test")
    public @ResponseBody String test(TestDto testDto){
        return testDto.toString(); // null
    }

    // POST: dto WELL populated from body json {"a"="azaz"}
    @RequestMapping(method = POST, path = "test")
    public @ResponseBody String postTest(@RequestBody TestDto testDto){
        return testDto.toString(); // "azaz"
    }

}
```

**DTO**:

```
public class TestDto {
    public String a;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Thanks !

[Full Spring boot sample to illustrate it](https://github.com/pleymor/test-request-params-to-dto)

Comment: Do you have getter setter in you TestDto class? if not can you add getter and setter and check?

Comment: you're not telling Spring that TestDto is part of the request in the get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing setter for the field.

```
 public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

should fix it.

Comment: created a branch to see the fix : https://github.com/pleymor/test-request-params-to-dto/tree/fix-request-params

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have done required configuration like having Jackson mapper in the class path, consume json attribute, getter and setter in DTO classes etc.

One thing missed here is, in **RequestMapping** use value attribute instead of path attribute as shown below

```
    @RequestMapping(method = POST, value= "/test", consumes="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String postTest(@RequestBody TestDto testDto){
        return testDto.toString(); 
    }
```

And, make sure that you set **content-type="application/json"** while sending the request

Comment: This method (POST) works perfectly.

It's the other (GET) which doesn't populate `testDto`

Comment: In GET request you cannot pass the json value. You have to use either PathParameter or RequestParameter

Comment: I don't intend to pass any json value in my GET request, but I try to do like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam

Comment: I was able to pass the values in the URL as you said. Only change I have is in **@RequestMapping** I have used **value** element to set the URL but you have used **path** element. Could you confirm which request mapping being used?

Comment: I'm using `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping`. I just added a repo in github to test the behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is not possible.  To access the query Parameter you have to use @RequestParam("a").  Then you just get the String. To get your object this way you have to pass json as Parameter.  a={"a":"azaz"}

Kind regards

Comment: According to this question it seems possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam