# spring @valid doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

i send a POST request of "application/json" type with 「postman」,set the param "phone" to empty string, normally it should print error for annotation "@NotEmpty", however, it didn't print anything and work well.

controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "verify_smscode", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseDto verifySmsCode(HttpServletRequest request,
      @Valid @RequestBody VerifySmsCodeParam params, Errors errors) {
    if(errors.hasErrors()) {
      System.out.println("error");
    }

    boolean success = userService.verifySmsCode(params.getPhone(), params.getSmsCode());

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("status", success);
    return new ResponseDto(result);
  }
```

Model:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VerifySmsCodeParam {

  @NotEmpty //import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
  private String phone;

  @NotEmpty
  private String smsCode;
}
```

SpringMvcConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.shit.voiceshare")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `BindingResult` .[this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) may be a good example of usage of this approach.

Comment: try to  use Validated instead of Valid

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing the dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also, make sure you import `NotNull` correctly.

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case adding of `@Validated` on top of RestController from `"org.springframework.validation.annotation"` solved the problem

Comment: Exactly what I was missing too.

Answer (score 1):

Am, I am still new in Spring. But here is an answer for my situation if it suits you.

To make @Valid work you should include two packages javax validation-api and hibernate-validator, but I only included validation-api.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with hibernate validator version 7.x.x. Works fine with 6.2.1.Final

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).