# Populate query parameters from DTO

Tags: spring, resttemplate, dto, query-string

Is there a way to let Spring populate `RestTemplate` query parameters automatically from a DTO, similarly to how it instantiates the response DTO automatically?

I wish to write something like:

```java
RequestDto request = new RequestDto();
request.setFoo("foo");
request.setBar("bar");

ResponseDto response = restTemplate.getForObject(
        "http://example.com/api",
        ResponseDto.class, 
        request
);
```

Instead of:

```java
ResponseDto response = restTemplate.getForObject(
        "http://example.com/api?foo={foo}&bar={bar}",
        ResponseDto.class,
        "foo",
        "bar"
);
```

Because there are many large DTOs, requiring tons of boilerplate code, which must be kept in sync with any DTO changes.

Spring 4.3.25

Comment: I am surprised that I cannot find an answer to this still and noone has answered yet. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is directly possible. The following is not exactly using the DTO, but it does let you build the request without having to form the URL string manually. You can use Spring's [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) class.

```java
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com/api")
    .queryParam("foo", "bar")
    // etc. ...
    .queryParam("bar", "foo");

String result = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.toString(), String.class);
```

You could loop over the DTO and build the query as above. Or without the DTO, you could use a `Map<String, String>` and loop over it.

```java
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("foo", "bar");

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com/api");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    builder.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.toString(), String.class);
```

Edit:

As crizzis suggested below, you can use [Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign)'s REST Client (from [Feign @QueryMap support](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-openfeign/2.1.5.RELEASE/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_querymap_support)):

> The OpenFeign @QueryMap annotation provides support for POJOs to be used as GET parameter maps. Unfortunately, the default OpenFeign QueryMap annotation is incompatible with Spring because it lacks a value property.

and

> Spring Cloud OpenFeign provides an equivalent @SpringQueryMap annotation, which is used to annotate a POJO or Map parameter as a query parameter map.

From your question's example:

```java
public class RequestDto {
  private string foo;
  private string bar;
}
```

```java
@FeignClient(name = "client", url = "http://example.com")
public interface FooTemplate {

    @GetMapping(path = "/api")
    String endpoint(@SpringQueryMap RequestDto requestDto);
}
```

Comment: Feign seems cool, but where do you specify the URL `http://example.com` to comply with the question?

Comment: @Snackoverflow You can do this by specifying the url in the annotation, i.e. `@FeignClient(name = "client", url = "https://example.com")`. I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this-

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://example.com/api")
        .queryParam("foo", "foo")
        .queryParam("bar", "bar");

ResponseDto response = restTemplate.getForObject(
        builder.buildAndExpand(builder).toUriString(),
        ResponseDto.class);
```

A more detailed answer can be found here- [RestTemplate: How to send URL and query parameters together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998790/resttemplate-how-to-send-url-and-query-parameters-together)

Answer (score 0):

How about using Feign? It allows you to describe the remote endpoint just like a Spring Controller. This includes support for query parameter DTOs.

See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546840/spring-cloud-openfeign-failed-to-create-dynamic-query-parameters)

Comment: The solution is unclear from the answer. Please post some example code on how we would implement this considering the code in the question. Links alone are not viable, because they are prone to expiry (even SO links, because posts can be removed or changed).

Comment: @Snackoverflow I added an example using Feign to my answer.