# How to map path params to gRPC object in spring based REST API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, grpc

My REST API ***must*** work with gRPC objects as input parameters.

The most simple example is:

`GET http://localhost:8083/api/books?page.number=1&page.size=30`

where the proto definition is:

```
message PagedMessage {
    Page page = 1;
}

message Page {
    int32 number = 1;
    int32 size = 2;
}
```

The controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/books")
public class ObjectOps {

   @Autowired
   private BooksService booksService;

   @GetMapping(value = "/")
   @ResponseBody
   BooksList listBooks(@RequestParam PagedMessage request) {
      return booksService.getBooks(request);
   }
}
```

And in the application I have [this bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/protobuf/ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter.html):

```
@Bean
ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter protobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter() {
      return new ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

The only way it worked for me is to pass the paging information as GET body:

```
{ 
   "page" : {
      "number": 1,
      "size": 30
   }
}
```

but it will be great to have the list books method object be populated from the request path parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just remove the `@RequestParam` annotation and Spring will populate the object.
Referenced by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942352/8075423

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for gRPC data objects (messages), but for plain POJOs.