# Micronaut - Bind Get parameter object in Controller

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I am implementing a Controller with a GET endpoint that is ought to receive the following request: `/mycontroller?myDate=2019-05-01`

My data class looks like this

```
data class MyData(
   val myDate: LocalDate
)
```

And my controller:

```
@Controller
class MyController {

  @Get("{?mydata*}")
  fun getMyEndpoint(mydata: MyData)...

}
```

Micronaut only binds the request in case I provide a default constructor for `MyData`, thus make `myDate` nullable or provide a default value - neither of those is what I wish to do.

Is there a way to get this working without providing the default constructor? Jackson e.g. can also handle it.

Thanks :)

Comment: "I was hoping that there is a way to bind the object itself directly without having to manually recreate the object:" What do you mean? What specifically isn't working?

Comment: "I am implementing a Controller with a GET endpoint that is ought to receive the following simplified data:" - Why do you want to send JSON to the server with a `GET` request?

Comment: In my real application I have about 8-10 parameters in my GET that I have to manually put together to an object. I was hoping that there is a way like in Spring to bind the object itself to the request, like you can do in spring. It works with dates and nested objects, too: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/parsing-of-localdate-query-parameters-in-spring-boot/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam. @JeffScottBrown I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Never used Micronaut, but it took me 20 seconds to find this, which seems to describe exactly what you want to do: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#binding

Comment: Yes, I know this works, but it does not give me the flexibility to e.g. parse dates from the parameter list. Or I do not see the way to do so.

Comment: The way it is done is described right after in the documentation: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#_bindable_types

Comment: @FlorianHansen I understand your answer to my question but I don't understand why you want it to be a `GET` request.

Comment: I see now that you changed the question and are no longer sending JSON.  This is a very different question now.

Comment: Generally POST is used to create resources on the server side. My endpoint is not doing so. I understand that one could also make a POST and use the body  with the data but I'd rather have a clean API design and not let technical difficulties enforce my design. :) So I understand that GET is also mit optimal but IT suits netter to my usecase. If I added the default constructor IT would work out well - I just try to find a was to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Full working example:**

```
import io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionContext
import io.micronaut.core.convert.TypeConverter
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.util.*
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Controller("/base")
class MyController {

   @Get("/path")
   fun getMyEndpoint(myData: MyData) {
      println("MyData: $myData")
   }

}

data class MyData(
   val myDate: LocalDate
)

@Singleton
class MyDataConverter : TypeConverter<String, MyData> {
   override fun convert(obj: String, targetType: Class<MyData>, context: ConversionContext?): Optional<MyData> =
      Optional.of(MyData(myDate = LocalDate.parse(obj)))
}
```

- Make a call to your server (e.g. if it running on port 8080):

  - http://localhost:8080/base/path?myData=2019-01-01
- You will see the output in the console of the server.

**Pro tip:** if you are using Jackson and Kotlin don't forget to include the [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) dependency:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$YourJacksonVersionHere"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. What happens in case MyData has more properties than just one?

Comment: You need to adapt `MyDataConverter` accordingly.

Comment: Yeah sure, but then I have a raw string and have to parse the MyData object manually from it?

Comment: Yes. You can do something like: `jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<MyData>(jsonString, MyData::class.java)`

Comment: But as someone else already stated: don't send json in a query parameter. Just do a post and put it in the body. This will save you trouble (i.e. encoding issues etc)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If Micronaut would not enforce me to provide the default constructor my code would work as I hope to, so I still have hopes to get it to work (:

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please think about upvoting. This is what keeps SO going ;)