# How to deserialize Enum value in Kotlin for @QueryValue annotation

Tags: kotlin, enums, jackson, annotations, micronaut

I am trying to get lower case letters from Kotlin Enum class when i pass the object in @QueryValue, but i am getting only upper case letters.

I have an enum in data class for example like below:

```
enum class StudentName{
    @JsonProperty("ram")
    RAM,
    @JsonProperty("sam")
    SAM
}
```

and i am using that enum like below:

```
data class StudentParams(
    @JsonProperty("studentName")
    val studentName: StudentName,
    @JsonProperty("age")
    val age: Int
)
```

I am passing this data class as request object in param value like below

```
@Post(POST_STUDENT_AGE)
fun postStudentAge(
    studentParams: StudentParams
): String
```

so in my URL, request object will go in params like --some url--/**&studentName=ram&age=20**

i need lower case letters from StudentName enum class here but getting only Upper case. When i pass the request object with @body annotation i am getting lower case letters in the request.

I tried enabling ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS also but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would help, but you can convert the `enum` to  `String` then invoke the `toLowerCase(locale)` function,

```
val ram = StudentName.RAM
val lowerCasedRam = ram.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.current)
```

when you pass a `StudentParams` to your `postStudentAge`,

```
postStudentAge(StudentParams(StudentName.RAM, 1))
```

you will do something like this.

```
fun postStudentAge(
    studentParams: StudentParams
) {
    val lowerCaseStudent = studentParams.studentName.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.current)
    
    // use lowercase student 
}
```

Calling

```
Log.e("StudentName", "$lowerCaseStudent")
```

prints

```
E/StudentName: ram
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set object as `QueryValue`. You have to write your own converter. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953893/micronaut-bind-get-parameter-object-in-controller).

Another way is write something like this:

```
@Post
    fun postStudentAge(
        @QueryValue studentName: StudentName,
        @QueryValue studentAge: Int
    ) {
        println(StudentParams(studentName, studentAge))
    }
```

Then you can pass `studentName` value in lowercase:

```
localhost:8080?studentName=ram&studentAge=32
```

And it will work