# Specific names for params if using complex object instead @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring

If I use `@RequestParam` in my controllers, I can name a variable different from the param name, if I set "name" attribute.

```
public String showSomething(@RequestParam(name = "field_1") String firstField /*other params*/) {
  return "viewName";
}
```

Can I name a variable different from the param name, if I use complex object?

**ComplexObject.java**

```
public class ComplexObject {
  private String firstField; // I want the value of the "field_1" parameter to get here
  private String secondField; // And "field_2" to get here

//getters, setters

}
```

**SimpleController.java**

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

  public String showSomething(ComplexObject complexObject) {
     return "viewName";
}
```

If possible, I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam)

Comment: No. I know how to use complex objects as param, I find alternative for "name" attribute @RequestParam annotation for complex object fields.

Comment: You could probably do this with a custom binder, but it's _really_ not worth the trouble. The entire point of the Web model is to represent the API between the server and client, and it's best for it to match as closely as possible.