# Spring MVC: Complex object with an array field as GET @RequestParam

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin

My issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam):
I don't want to have a lot of parameters in my controller, so I moved them all to a separate class.

```kotlin
class FilterRequest(
    val storeCode: List<String>,
    val extOrderId: List<String>,
    val name: String,    
    
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    val createDate: LocalDate?,
    
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    val lastModifiedDate: LocalDate?
)
```

Controller

```kotlin
@GetMapping
fun getByFilters(request: FilterRequest, pageable: Pageable){...}
```

If I send a request like this

```
?extOrderId=200600774995,200600774
```

all values are stored a single cell.

And If I send it like this

```
?extOrderId=200600774995&extOrderId=200600774
```

values go to separate cells.

Is there any way to pass multiple values as a parameter and have these values stored in separate cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by changing `val` to `var` in the FilterRequest class