# What is a good way to pass many parameters to controller?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, rest

I have an application on Java (Spring framework) and Javascript (AngularJs framework). There are list of objects in the table and two text fields for filtering this objects. Filtering happens on the server side so I pass these values from text fields to @RestController's method as params and then to the repository method.
Client side:

```
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/messages',
            params: {sender: $scope.sender, recipient: $scope.recipient}
        }).then(
            function (res) {
                $scope.messages = res.data;
            },
            function (res) {
                console.log("Error: " + res.status + " : " + res.data);
            }
        );
```

Server side:

```
    @GetMapping("/messages")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Message> getMessagesWithFilters(@RequestParam(required = true) String sender,
                                                @RequestParam(required = true) String recipient) {
      
        List<Message> messages = messageRepository.findBySenderNumberAndRecipientNumber(sender, recipient); 
        return messages;
    }
```

It's pretty easy when there're only two filters but what should I do if there are 10 or 20 of them? Is there a good way to do this, should I pass them as Map or something like that?

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/@AADota/spring-passing-list-and-array-of-values-as-url-parameters-1ed9bbdf0cb2

Comment: Aditionally, you can use `@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params`, which would give you a `Map` where the key is the param name, and the value is a `List` of all the values given for that param.

Comment: [This post and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam) may be interesting aswell.

Comment: @locus2k thanks but I need to be able to define what filter was passed, it's not very convenient to do with this method

Comment: @BeUndead I was just thinking about it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this Annotation `@ModelAttribute` like :

```java
@GetMapping("/messages")
@ResponseBody
public List<Message> getMessagesWithFilters(@ModelAttribute Filter filter) {   
        List<Message> messages = messageRepository.findBySenderNumberAndRecipientNumber(filter.sender, filter.recipient); 
        return messages;
}
```

and Filter.java

```java
public class Filter {
    public String sender;
    public String recipient;
}
```

You might then use `filter.sender` and `filter.recipient` in your controller

Comment: Is it better than using Map? If so, why?

Comment: A Map may contain any <key, value> whereas ModelAttribute force types and allow multiple types without explicit cast

Comment: Also you may use the same class for different endpoints with easy refactor (as it's on a class and not in a string used as a map key).