# Deserialize Params into object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping, path-variables, get-mapping

I have a URL abc.com/loc/lat=90.6&long=44.6&sf='random' here lat and long are required and sf is an optional param. I have created a class with these three as data members, how can I deserialize those params into that class object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam)

Answer (score 0):

SpringMVC will do that 'mapping' for you.

Look at the following piece of code.

There is a REST controller with one method. It expects the **Request** object. This object has three fields, just like you need. All of your street parameters will be mapped to the object fields automatically.

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/loc")
    public @ResponseBody
    Request myAction(Request reqObject) {
        System.out.println("reqObject = " + reqObject);
            return reqObject;
    }
}

class Request {
    float lat;
    float longt;
    String sf;

    public float getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(float lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public float getLong() {
        return longt;
    }

    public void setLong(float longt) {
        this.longt = longt;
    }

    public String getSf() {
        return sf;
    }

    public void setSf(String sf) {
        this.sf = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Request{" +
                "lat=" + lat +
                ", longt=" + longt +
                ", sf='" + sf + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

How to call it:

> http://localhost:8080/loc?lat=90.6&long=44.6&sf=random

This is what you will get printed out:

> {"lat":90.6,"sf":"random","long":44.6}

Try this out.

Note, how I had to name your **long** variable differently, this is because *long* is a reserved keyword in Java. We can't use it for a variable name. But we can define *getters and setters* in a way we like. **getLong** and **setLong** allow us to map 'long' parameter to the variable we need.

------------ Version of POJO class for Lombock lovers:

```java
   @Data
    @ToString
    class Request {
        @NonNull
        float lat;
        @NonNull
        float longt;

        String sf;
    }
```

With Lombok adding its magic, I have not found a way to handle your ***long*** input parameter. I suggest you to change it to '**longt**' to make it work.

You will be calling your service like this:

> http://localhost:8080/loc?lat=90.6&longt=44.6&sf=random

Comment: Hey thanks for response, I am using lombok, with non null annotations, where should I put the checks such that on and lat a can never be null?

Comment: I see, I like Lombok, let me update my answer. Please, do not forget to 'like' it :)

Comment: I have changed my variable name, now suppose if someone hit URL with wrong spelling if param, what will happen?

Comment: Also, what if request violates nonnull constraint?

Comment: If a request is not correct, you will get an error response. Try that out