# How to use custom class in the swagger API

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, codegen

In my previous post

[How to accept multiple query parameters with different parameter name in one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328987/how-to-accept-multiple-query-parameters-with-different-parameter-name-in-one-cla)

I learned about passing the query parameters, and I also achieved it
But now the problem is I am in a swagger setup where I use codegen for generating API default code which provides me an interface using which I implement it into my controller layer and overrides those methods and add my logic

The problem is I have an internal api-doc file that generates a custom code, in that file how should I mention that I am using my own custom class for passing it to be used as a query parameter object? Currently, my api doc file looks like below. Problem with below file is I have to define each and every query parameter and as I learned in my previous stack article that we can wrap it into an class object. But my question here is how should I mention path to my custom class into this file.

```
  /tasks:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: 'api-params.yaml#/name'
        - $ref: 'api-params.yaml#/age'
        - $ref: 'api-params.yaml#/credentials'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                  $ref: 'api-resp.yaml#/someResponse'
        "401":
          description: "Unauthorized"
          content: { }
        "403":
          description: "Forbidden"
          content: { }
```

And also can we directly define a model using swagger? If yes how can we do that?
I mean I am using custom models for referring them to be used as request body and I usually mention them like below, but my question is can we use similar behaviour for queryParams also

```
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/RquestBodyPayload'
```

but is the similar this is also allowed for query parameters ?