# Spring MVC: GET with wrapped generic value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a generic wrapper type to be used in multiple DTOs that are used as input parameters to HTTP GET endpoints, but Spring deserializes the value as "String" instead of the correct generic type.

For example, consider this controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

   @Data
   public static class Wrapper<T extends Comparable<?>> {
      private T value;
   }

   @Data
   public static class Dto{
      private Wrapper<LocalDate> dateValue;
   }

   @GetMapping("/demo")
   public void sample(Dto dto) {
      LocalDate value = dto.dateValue.value;
      System.out.println(value);
   }
}
```

When invoking the endpoint like this in the browser:
http://localhost:8080/demo?dateValue.value=2023-11-06

I get the following error, because "dto.value" has been deserialized as String instead of LocalDate:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.time.LocalDate (java.lang.String and java.time.LocalDate are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

**Is there any way to tell Spring: "Hey, please convert the value of my wrapper to LocalDate before invoking my endpoint"?**

I think the underlying cause of this is Java type erasure and initially I was suspecting a Jackson deserialization issue. For that I found solutions, e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization.

But now I *think* in the case of GET request params, Jackson is not even involved (because there's no JSON to deserialize, only query parameters, right?)... and I can't find any good sources. The closest thing I found is this SO thread, but it's missing the tricky "generics" part: [Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam)

I feel like I'm missing something super obvious here and just didn't type the right search keywords yet.

I reproduced this in an example app based on Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.1.5 - if necessary I can push it to some Github repo.

Comment: A note: Currently I am using a subclass of Wrapper with concrete generic type as a workaround:

`public static class LocalDateWrapper extends Wrapper<LocalDate> { }`

And change Dto to use `private LocalDateWrapper dateValue;`