# Populate user session after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to put some values (String and Integer values) in user session after successful login.

I'm using Spring MVC + Spring Security (both v3.2.x) in my web app.

Is there some common approach with Spring to intercept session start? Is it correct to implement a `HttpSessionListener` and register it in my application?

Comment: You can register HttpSessionListener. Another, maybe worse way is to use @PostConstruct in your session class.

Comment: A simple and commonly used approach is, once login is successful, get session object and put key value pair in session object. I am not sure this approach is applicable to your code or not. If not kindly add method where login logic is written.

Comment: How are you authenticating user? Is it acceptable for you to pass those values to principal object?

Comment: The accepted answer here has some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791645/how-to-use-session-attributes-in-spring-mvc

Comment: A common way is to use a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally decided to implement a custom [`ApplicationListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) to handle user login:

```
public class LoggedUserListener implements
        ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession session;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        session.setAttribute("key", "value");

    }

}
```

and declared a bean in my Spring config:

```
<bean class="it.webapp.LoggedUserListener" />
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: I had to add a DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher for the events to be fired

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring MVC + Spring Security, it might be worth checking out `org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher`

The [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionEventPublisher.html) for the class says:

> Publishes HttpSessionApplicationEvents to the Spring Root
>   WebApplicationContext.
>
> Maps javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated() to
>   HttpSessionCreatedEvent.

My understanding is that you need to add:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

And your class needs to extend `ApplicationListener` in order to receive these events

```
public class SessionPopulatorThing implements ApplicationListener<HttpSessionCreatedEvent>{

//repository, service attributes go here

public void onApplicationEvent(HttpSessionCreatedEvent httpSessionCreatedEvent){
//populate with defaults 
}

}
```

The main benefit is that it's compatible with Spring Core + Spring Security and with a little bit of extra configuration on top of this you can get concurrency management features in session management with Spring Security as well. There's more about this in the [spring security reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html):