# SpringMVC Controller Method Doesn't Bring in Model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I noticed that when a Form Submit happens, my handler method that captures a @Model object as a parameter does have a valid Model available to me, e.g.

```
public ModelAndView save(final HttpServletRequest request, 
             @ModelAttribute(MODEL_NAME) MyModel model,
             BindingResult bindingResult)
```

But when I have a handler method corresponding to a URL redirect from a simple `<a href="..">` button/link, e.g.

```
<a href="myController.do&function=add">
```

leading to

```
@RequestMapping(params = "function=add")
public ModelAndView add(final HttpServletRequest request, 
          @ModelAttribute(MODEL_NAME) MyModel model) throws Exception
```

in that case, the model object is NULL. The model wasn't carried through the request and made available to me in the handler method.

Is there a way to reexpose the model? I do have the same param in both methods, but in the 2nd one the "model" object is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GET request with  you will need to add the model to the URL. Or you can use POST with a form instead.

See: [how to pass a java object from jsp to spring controller on clicking a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462811/how-to-pass-a-java-object-from-jsp-to-spring-controller-on-clicking-a-link)

Comment: But the model can't be serialized into a string? How would it be made into a string param?

Comment: And I *really* don't want to use Session attributes, that's horrible