# How to Http session management in spring MVC get data in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/log"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String login(HttpSession session, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        User u;
        List<Map<String,Object>> list=rdao.getuserdata(u);

        if(member !=null) 
        {
        session.setAttribute("MEMBER", member); 
         return "taskform";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid user name or password");
        }
        return "loginup";
    }   


in above code how to set httpsession
```

Comment: Hey, please take a look in to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942106/how-to-manage-session-in-spring-mvc?rq=1

Comment: it's not a correct Ans

Comment: The link can help you to find out an answer. In you code you are setting "MEMBER" as a session attribute and providing value for that attribute. So what do you mean by 'how to set httpSession', Can you please elaborate what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Sir, my question is a how to get data in Dao class in declare in controller