# How Can i set an object array in session in Spring

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<GWLData> getGwlList = runMatcherDao.fetchData();
```

Here getGwlList is an ArrayList of Objects of GWLData class. I want to store the getGwlList in session in spring. Moreover how can i access that session variable letter ? Any help is deeply appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use session scoped beans or you can inject Session object to your bean. There is a simillar question here [How to use Session attributes in Spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791645/how-to-use-session-attributes-in-spring-mvc)