# Accesing annotated Spring session bean in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My bean is annotated with

```
@Component("Person")
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

I have some getters and setters but the one I'm interested in to get in my JSP is

```
@Transient
    private ArrayList<DummyProduct> products = new ArrayList<DummyProduct>();

    public ArrayList<DummyProduct> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(ArrayList<DummyProduct> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
```

Then in my controller I add products to that list

```
DummyProduct prod = new DummyProduct(product);
this.person.getProducts().add(prod);
```

Then in my JSP I tried, with no luck to get the products:

```
<table id="cart_table" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="prd" items="${sessionScope.Person.products}" >
<tr>
<td>${prd.productName}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

I've also used the following property so that my beans are exposed to jsps: `<beans:property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes"`

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            <beans:property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true" />
```

EDIT: The controller:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(value= "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProduct(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam String product){
        DummyProduct prod = new DummyProduct(product);
        this.person.getProducts().add(prod);
        return "loggedIn";
    }

}
```

Table is always empty. I've debugged and I saw that in my person bean, the products list is populated.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the bean without the `scessionScope` before it?

Comment: @nfechner I tried now but not working :(

Comment: can we see your controller class ?

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte done :)

Comment: Did you annotated your class with the : @Controller  ? I guess you did so

Comment: @Marius-CristianDragan try to add the Transient annotation to the getProducts() method not to the attribute

Comment: Don't use `${sessionScope.Person.products}` use `${Person.products}`.

Comment: @cralfaro I used Transient on variable because I'm using Hibernate and  if not, Hibernate will complain that I miss that column in my database.

Comment: @Marius-CristianDragan I know and is ok, but the annotation should be places at method level not attribute

Comment: @cralfaro if I use it only on the method, Hibernate complains. If I use it on both field and method, I still don't get it in my JSP page. I tried both with sessionScope and without it :(

Comment: @Marius-CristianDragan check this link, maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791645/how-to-use-session-attributes-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @cralfaro thank you!! the second solution solved my problem. Adding @SessionAttributes("person") to my Controller did the trick :D Could you please answer the question so I can accept your answer?:)

Comment: @Marius-CristianDragan great! i will then can be useful for more people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related with the way you are accessing to the session attribute.

Change to this

**UPDATED**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("person")
```

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791645/how-to-use-session-attributes-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: It's actually 
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("person")
I always use the Controller as singleton :)

Comment: @Marius-CristianDragan Thanks! just edited with your comment