# How to show list of object in Thymeleaf in spring boot project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, arraylist, thymeleaf

I am new to Java and programming, I have just finished Java courses and now learning to use Springboot with thymeleaf and maven.

I can pass and show information with single objects but I cannot create and show the list containing these.  I know this could be done with Repository but I am trying to figure this out without using it to understand the basics before moving on to repositories. I get Whitelabel error page, I know it's all wrong but I would really appreciate if someone could teach me how to do it as simple as possible. Thanks!

```java
 public class FriendController {

     @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public String friendFrom (Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("friend", new Friend());
         return "/hello";
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public String friendSubmit(Friend name, Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("friend", name);
         ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
         friends.add(new Friend());
         return "/hello";
     }

}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>List of friends</h1>

    <table>
        <tr th:each="${friends}">
        <td th:text="${friend.name}">

        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- This one worked on it's own -->
    <h1>ADD INFO</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/hello}" th:object="${friend}" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ADD NAME: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```java
public class Friend {

    private String name;



    public Friend() {
        super();
    }


    public Friend(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Friend [name=" + name + "]";
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }




}
```

Comment: The view has access to the model. But you never put any list in the model.

Answer (score 4):

you have two mistakes;

1. add your friends list to model object in `friendSubmit` method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public String friendSubmit(Friend name, Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("friend", name);
         ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
         friends.add(new Friend());
         model.addAttribute("friends", friends); // add this line to your code
         return "/hello";
     }
```

2. in thymeleaf:

```
<table>
        <tr th:each="friend : ${friends}"> // add friend
        <td th:text="${friend.name}"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

also if you need get submited object, you have to use `@ModelAttribute`,
and instead of adding empty object to list, add `@ModelAttribute`'s object to list:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public String friendSubmit(@ModelAttribute Friend friend, Model model) { // @ModelAttribute added
         model.addAttribute("friend", friend);
         ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
         //friends.add(new Friend()); 
         friends.add(friend);
         model.addAttribute("friends", friends); // add this line to your code
         return "/hello";
     }
```

and you should add your list to session in order to keep alive your objects for all requests.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public String friendSubmit(@ModelAttribute Friend friend, Model model, 
                                HttpSession session) { // add HttpSession here
         model.addAttribute("friend", friend);
         ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
         //friends.add(new Friend()); 
         friends.add(friend);
         //model.addAttribute("friends", friends);
         session.setAttribute("friends", friends); // add this line to your code
         return "/hello";
     }
```

in thymeleaf:

```
<table>
        <tr th:each="friend : ${session.friends}"> // add session variable
        <td th:text="${friend.name}"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this help you, good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this got to program showing at least, but still I don't understand how to show the whole list.. just one object showing at time.. :( @Ismayil Ibrahimov

Comment: you should add your list to session in order to keep alive your objects for all requests. please check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791645/how-to-use-session-attributes-in-spring-mvc