# Is there something like model.addAttribute() but for individual users?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**[Solved]** I was wrong at so many levels, key concept was `session` [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795626/13771772), i follow this way

```java
 String index(HttpSession session) {
            session.setAttribute("mySessionAttribute", "someValue");
            return "index";
        }
```

```html
<p th:text="${session.ShoppingCart.prop}" th:unless="${session == null}"> . </p>
```

---

I have a simple **Spring boot** app with **Thymeleaf**, the way I pass data to html from Controller is by using org.springframework.ui.Model;, it works fine but this data is accesible by everyone. The data is fetched from a public weather api, is not sensible but it is unique by user, the app is public and has not login so I can't store user state in a database.

I'm looking for something like a `LocalStorage` but for **Spring** a way to identify each user and store temporaly that data and then pass it to thymeleaf.

I thought about creating a **random id** on client browser, send it to server and persist the user info there, i will identify each user by cookies (if no cookie -> new id) but then.. how could I pass that info to thymeleaf? "privately".

The way i am used to handle that on previous apps was consuming the view directly on Js
I am pretty new, and i feel that maybe I am missing some key concept here.

thank you guys.

Here is the flow:
Controller.java

```java
@GetMapping("/something")
public String something(Model model) {
    model.addAtributte("something",something);
    return "index";
    }
```

index.html

```html
<p class="card" th:text="${something}"></p>
```

And here is what im looking

```java
@GetMapping("/something")
public String something(MyPrivateModel notForEveryoneModel) {
    
    notForEveryoneModel.addAtributte("something",something);
    return "index";
    }
```

```html
<p class="card" th:text="${ [notForEveryoneModel].something}"></p>
```

Comment: How do you know that the data is unique to user if it's public? Why don't you just put a login form? And finally how will you distinguish the same person connecting with different computers or browsers etc.?

Comment: A `Model` is only living for a single request, so imho you are overthinking things.