# How to call the session using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a beginner of spring boot application. I made login form success when login success redirects to the index page along with session username set in the index page. I don't know how to set and retrieve into index page of the login success.
This is what I have tried and have attached below.

**UserController**

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user ) {
        
        User oauthUser = userService.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        System.out.print(oauthUser);
        if(Objects.nonNull(oauthUser)) 
        {   
            
            return "redirect:/";
            HttpSession.setAttribute("users",user.getUsername());
            
        } else {
            return "redirect:/login";
            
        
        }

}
```

**UserService**

```
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    
      private UserRepository repo;
    
    public User login(String username, String password) {
        User user = repo.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Index** if the login succes only displayed welcome only

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

        <h1>Welcome to Home Page</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use jsp expressions to get the "users" attribute like this <℅username = request.getAttribute("users")℅> in your index.jsp file and  just do ${username} to render it. I would suggest the use of JSTL tags for forms that help you get the modelAttribute automatically injected into it. So that you get to access the variables directly into the form that you set in the controller.

Comment: can you write it it is very help ful please

Comment: I could have written the answer @raduba but m not 100% sure if it would surely solve ur issue. Can you try adding this expression in ur index.jsp file like this <h1><℅=session.getAttribute("users")℅></h1> and try?

Comment: ok sir. if i written in HttpSession.setAttribute("users",user.getUsername());  on my controller getting error of Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setAttribute(String, Object) from the type HttpSession

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795626/11045279 this should help.