# Spring MVC cannot find method in controller when using POST request

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
I am new to spring and I am facing the following issue:
```

Edited Description:

I was able to make a POST call by making a new controller and ModelAndView method but now I am facing one more problem of data not getting passed from JSP to controller.
    My JSP code is:

```
form:form method="POST" action="UserOperation"
        modelAttribute="DebitModel">
        <h3>Debit</h3>

                    <c:if test="${!empty listAccounts}">
                        <select name="item" id="account_dropdown"
                            onchange="changeAccountDetails(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                            <c:forEach items="${listAccounts}" var="account">
                                <option
                                    value="${account.accID},${account.acctype},${account.balance}">AccID:
                                    ${account.accID} Balance: ${account.balance}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <label ><b>Account ID: </b></label>
                        <label id="accIdText" path="accID">${listAccounts[0].accID}</label>
                        <label><b>Account Type: </b></label>
                        <label id="accTypeText" path="acctype">${listAccounts[0].acctype}</label>
                        <label><b>Balance: </b></label>
                        <label id="accBalText" path="balance">${listAccounts[0].balance}</label>
                    </c:if>
                    <br> <br> Enter Amount<input type="text"
                        id="amount" width="80" path="amount"></input> <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Debit"></input>
    </form:form>
```

There is a normal bean class named DebitModel.
I tried to search and at many places for the data not getting passed and found solution as form:input mentioned but if I use this I get no Binding FoundException 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'DebitModel' available as request attribute
' even if <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> is present.

```
The Controller class Code:

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/UserOperation")
public class DebitController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountService mAccountService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registerCustomer(@ModelAttribute("DebitModel") DebitModel debitModel, BindingResult result,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, FileNotFoundException {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        System.out.println("data------------------------" + debitModel.toString());
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post that working GET method.

Comment: This is just a suggestion can you try using (at) RequestBody instead of (at)ModelAttribute . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824012/spring-modelattribute-vs-requestbody . @a007

Comment: Show your spring mvc configuration.

Answer (score 0):

show your controller class.

Seems you are using wrong pattern in path defining. Try with changing **"/UserHomeDebit"** to **"UserHomeDebit"** in both jsp and controller level.

This can check with the browser url when you are submitting the form. Lets think your application name is **sampleapplication**.then url will be

**http://localhost:8080/sampleapplication**

Then if you are use /UserHomeDebit as controller path mapping then url will change as following.

**http://localhost:8080/UserHomeDebit**

so its is wrong the correct one must be

**http://localhost:8080/sampleapplication/UserHomeDebit**

So just change the path as i said earlier and check

Answer (score 0):

In `<form:form>` tag's action attribute you have to specify full URL path to your application. There are several ways to do it but two of the simplest and elegant are: first by specifying an url by `<c:url>` tag. To do so, first you need to declare JSTL c prefix. You can do it by attaching following line at the beginning of the jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Then to set the expected url (http://localhost:8080/[your-app-name]**/UserOperation**):

```
<c:url value="/UserOperation" var="actionUrl" />
```

And pass that url variableto to *action* attribute of the form:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${actionUrl}" ...
```

Second solution to do this, simpler but not sure if more elegant is to get the context url of your app Spring Expression Language directly in the `action` attribute and attach part of url corresponding to your Controller method:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/UserOperation" ...
```