# Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----...;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to send an object to the controller that has several lists with files and several fields with plain text.

```
public class ContributionNew<T extends MovieInfoDTO> {
    private List<T> elementsToAdd;
    private Map<Long, T> elementsToUpdate;
    private Set<Long> idsToDelete;
    private Set<String> sources;
    private String comment;
}

public class Photo extends MovieInfoDTO {
    private MultipartFile photo;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/{id}/contributions/photos")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public
ResponseEntity<Void> createPhotoContribution(
        @ApiParam(value = "The movie ID", required = true)
        @PathVariable("id") final Long id,
        @ApiParam(value = "The contribution", required = true)
        @RequestBody @Valid final ContributionNew<Photo> contribution
) {
```

I am sending data using [postman](https://zapodaj.net/d22ba9788f302.png.html). However, he throws me away

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywY7ByvgonAjDoaCT;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

What should I set the Content-type for this controller so that I can send an object that has fields of plain text and lists with files?

If I set the header in the header

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
```

it throws me in the console

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but `multipart/form-data` should not have a `charset`. It does need a `boundary` though. See [WWW Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

Comment: More likely, though, it is the `----` in the `boundary` that cause trouble, since `--` has special meaning for boundary markers.

Comment: @RequestBody means to parse JSON data into map or java beans and only support content type is "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 65):

As said dknight @RequestBody means use of JSON or XML data with maps your DTO bean.
In case of MultipartFile you can't use JSON data so you can't use @RequestBody.
Try with @ModelAttribute annotation.

Working sample :

```
@PostMapping("/promoters")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<PromoterDTO> createPromoter(@ModelAttribute PromoterDTO promoterDTO) throws URISyntaxException { ... }
```

With PromoterDTO like this :

```
    public class PromoterDTO implements Serializable {

        private Long id; 

        private String name;

        private String address;

        private MultipartFile logo;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting null values in my object after implementing this. All the fields are null

Comment: Have you set the getters and setters ?

Comment: If I use @ModelAttribute in my case, I get that it can't convert from string to my child DTO (my main DTO has other DTO in it). How can I fix that?

Comment: Doing exactly as this states the DTO is populated correctly but the variable "logo" ist still `null`. Any ideas?

Comment: Also in my case the file field is null after. With ModelAttribute the object is saved in database (with RequestBody i was not able to do it) but the file field is null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 34):

In Postman, you need to set the body to be of type raw, and from the drop down you can select JSON, I had a similar issue, this fixed my issue.

[image: view screen here]

Comment: How does this allow the upload of files as well?

Answer (score 8):

Hi Folks simply change : @RequestBody to @ModelAttribute

```
public ResponseEntity<DTO> exemple(@ModelAttribute Dto dto) throws TechnicalException
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `@RequestBody`, use `@RequestParam`!

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this will fix the OP's problem?

Comment: to send files content-type should be multipart/form-data so requestparam takes in formdata but  for request body content-type should be application/json that not handle files.

Answer (score 5):

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
```

Use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`. It worked for me.

Comment: Hi my friend, That works for me...

Answer (score 4):

use @ModelAttribute instead of @ResponseBody as this takes up data in key value pairs and the later is used for an object like, json.
While hitting the api simply pass the multipart type and json key value pairs of the object. It works fine!

[stack overflow question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824012/spring-modelattribute-vs-requestbody)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of @RequestBody, use @ModelAttribute like,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}/contributions/photos")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public
ResponseEntity<Void> createPhotoContribution(
        @ApiParam(value = "The movie ID", required = true)
        @PathVariable("id") final Long id,
        @ApiParam(value = "The contribution", required = true)
        @ModelAttribute @Valid final ContributionNew<Photo> contribution
) {
```

Answer (score 2):

produces = { "application/json" } has to written in the controller instead of consumes = { "application/json" }

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full code sample written in Kotlin using Spring Boot 2.1.7

Example uses a `ProfileRepository` that would be something you implement of course.

Kotlin is nice, because the `data class` implements serializable already.

**Take note, that you have to use `var` not `val` for the model objects properties otherwise the field values will be null in the log message.**

```kotlin
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

@RestController
class ExampleController(private val myProfileRepository: ProfileRepository) {
    
    @PostMapping("/api/uploadFile")
    fun createProvider(@ModelAttribute request: CreateProfileRequest): Provider {
        println("received create request with photo: ${request.photo} for the following person ${request.name}")
        return myProfileRepository.save(Provider(name = request.name!!))
    }
}

data class CreateProfileRequest(
    var name: String? = null,
    var photo: MultipartFile? = null
)
```