# Spring ModelAttribute can't convert string into nested data class

Tags: spring, kotlin, deserialization, multipartform-data

I have a spring controller endpoint that I want to use to accept FormData from the front end. I was reading [a guide on the @ModelAnnotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation) and found [other stackoverflow posts on accepting FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051177/content-type-multipart-form-databoundary-charset-utf-8-not-supported) and it seems like I have my controller set up correctly:

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
class RouteFeatureController() {

    @PostMapping("/route/{routeId}/feature")
    fun saveRouteFeature(
        @ModelAttribute details: RouteFeature,
        @PathVariable routeId: Int
    ): String {
        return "worked"
        // I cut the rest of the actual code b/c it's not relevant to the question
    }
}
```

One of the difference in my case through is that the `RouteFeature` data class that I'm trying to translate the form data into has a nested object in it:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class RouteFeature(
    val description: String,
    val point: GeographicCoordinates,
    val image: MultipartFile? = null
)
```

and `GeographicCoordinates` looks like this:

```
data class GeographicCoordinates(
    @JsonProperty("lat")
    val latitude: Float,
    @JsonProperty("lng")
    val longitude: Float
)
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I send up my form data from the front end I get an error on the server (note: I'm not sending an image up with the payload to simplify the example. the image is optional for the data class anyway):

[image: error in browser]

[image: server error]

Specifically, the server seems to have a problem deserializing the string version of the geographic coordinates into the data class:

> [Field error in object 'routeFeature' on field 'point': rejected value [{"lat":38.58421186285306,"lng":-90.30766141223212}]; codes [typeMismatch.routeFeature.point,typeMismatch.point,typeMismatch.com.lightinspiration.headsupridenotifier.domain.GeographicCoordinates,typeMismatch];
>
> ...
>
> Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.lightinspiration.headsupridenotifier.domain.GeographicCoordinates': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I can't seem to find a solution that explains how to get the nested data class to deserialize correctly.

Any ideas?