# @ModelAttribute rejected object with List field

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following endpoint

```
@PutMapping
ResponseEntity<MyObject> updateMyObject(@ModelAttribute MyObjectDTO myObjectDTO) {
    ...
}
```

And my DTO is

```
@Value
class MyObjetDTO {
    ...
    List<ChildDTO> children;
}
```

And my child DTO is

```
@Value
class ChildDTO {
    ...
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

In the UI, I send the request using form data (I need to do this since I have a multipart field in my DTO):

```
const formData = new FormData();
...
formData.append("children", JSON.stringify([]));
axios.put("http://localhost:8080/api, formData, {})...
```

I got this error on backend:

`Failed to convert value of tyoe "java.lang.String" to required type "java.lang.List"`

Comment: Have you tried to append an empty list without `JSON.stringify`? `formData.append("children", []);`

Comment: It results to the same error.

Comment: Can you use 
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
 when you wanna call?

Comment: better use @requestbody but https://stackoverflow.com/a/31990142/175554 may help

Comment: yes because the `children` field in your DTO is expecting a `List`, but you are sending it as a string in the form data!

Answer (score 2):

Your Spring `Controller` is waiting for information received as form data.

When Spring tries to build the backend object `MyObjectDTO` from the information provided in the submitted HTTP request with your `axios` call, it expects `children` to be a property of type `List` as your defined it:

```java
List<ChildDTO> children;
```

But instead you are providing a `String`, `[]`, in your form data:

```java
formData.append("children", JSON.stringify([]));
```

If you want to pass an empty value for the `children` property, please, instead don't pass any value for it.

If you need to pass a value for say a list of two `children`, you need to index then, and pass that information to your `Controller`, something like:

```js
formData.append("children[0].id", "3");
formData.append("children[0].name", "a name");
formData.append("children[1].id", "5");
formData.append("children[1].name", "another name");
```

As an alternative, as suggested as well by @ozkanpakdil in his comment and [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824012/spring-modelattribute-vs-requestbody/31990142#31990142), please, consider serializing your entire form to JSON format and use `@RequestBody` in your `Controller` instead.