"@ModelAttribute returns null when passing JSON in Spring Boot POST request"
I am try to create simple to-do list api.Inside it i have implement add task functionality in controller but when i pass json format using postman api unable to get proper value of param content inspit of this i got null why this happen
@PostMapping("/create")
    public User addTask(@ModelAttribute User users) {
        
        
        User user=new User();
        user.setContent(users.getContent());
        user.setDone(false);
        System.out.println(users.getContent());
        return todoService.addTask(user);
    }

json format passing param value,got content null value](https://i.sstatic.net/Ik8XQpWk.png)
I want to extract the content value entered by user, and wanted to get actual value in-spite of null.

When you are passing the data through JSON body , we need to use @RequestBody annotation.
@PostMapping("/create") 
public User addTask(@RequestBody User users) {

    User user=new User();
    user.setContent(users.getContent());
    user.setDone(false);
    System.out.println(users.getContent());
    return todoService.addTask(user);
}

@ModelAttribute is used when you want to pass the data through the URL params.
For more info, refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824012/spring-modelattribute-vs-requestbody#:~:text=With%20%40ModelAttribute%2C%20you%20pass%20data,pass%20it%20as%20JSON%20body.

Thank you so much for  your valuable response
