# Spring 3 MVC:Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am new to Spring 3 MVC and was trying out a simple validation example. Below is the controller class:

```
@Controller
public class ValidationController {

@RequestMapping(value="/input")
public String displayForm(ModelMap model){      
    model.addAttribute("empl",new Employee());
    return "input";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateForm(@Valid Employee empl, BindingResult result, ModelMap m){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Validation Failed!!!");
        return "input";
    }else{
        System.out.println("Validation Succeeded!!!");
        return "done";
    }
}
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
@Size(min=2,max=30)
private String name;
@NotEmpty @Email
private String email;
@NotNull @Min(18) @Max(35)
private Integer age;
@Size(min=10)
private String phone;
    // Getters and Setters
```

Below is the input.jsp file:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="empl" action="validate">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="nameInput">Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="name" id="nameInput"/>
            <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="ageInput">Age:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="age" id="ageInput"/>
            <form:errors path="age" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="phoneInput">Phone:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="phone" id="phoneInput"/>
            <form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="emailInput">Email:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="email" id="emailInput"/>
            <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
        </td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

**Problem:**

On click of the `submit button of the`input.jsp` file, I am getting the below exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'empl' available as request attribute
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:424)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

For resolving this I changed the validation method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateForm(@Valid Employee empl, BindingResult result, ModelMap m){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Validation Failed!!!");
        m.addAttribute("empl",new Employee());
        return "input";
    }else{
        System.out.println("Validation Succeeded!!!");
        return "done";
    }
}
```

And now the error messages are not getting displayed.

Kindly help me in resolving this so that the validation error messages gets displayed in the `input.jsp` screen.

Comment: Try supplying `@ModelAttribute("empl")` right before `@Valid`

Comment: @geoand yes now it works. Please explain the reasona nd post your answer so that I can close this thread.

Comment: Also how is this one working? They have not used the `@ModelAttribute` in the demo. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@ModelAttribute("empl")` right before `@Valid`, in order for Spring MVC to be able to know that it should populate the model object with the inputs of the form with `commandName="empl"`

Your controller method should look like

`public String validateForm(@ModelAttribute("empl") @Valid Employee empl, BindingResult result, ModelMap m)`

When you are trying to display errors in a form Spring MVC needs to have a reference to the offending model. So when you changed your code and added  `new Employee()` there where no errors on that object.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423501/2504224) SO post has a good explanation of what `@ModelAttribute` does as does [this](http://www.javabeat.net/modelattribute-spring-mvc/) and [this](http://blog.nigelsim.org/2011/09/07/spring-mvc-validation-bindingresult/) blog post

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But my question is: without using `@ModelAttribute` also the values are coming in the `@Controller` class. I went through the links but it did not answer my doubt.

Comment: Also, in thiese URL's I can see they have not used any @ModelAttribute - WHY? Please clarify. The URL's I followed are: 1) http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/  2) http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation

Comment: I am not exactly sure why in those tutorials they are able to omit `@ModelAttribute`. I could not find anything specific on that issue

Comment: @user182944 @geoand If you omit `@ModelAttribute`, a form bean will be exposed as a model attribute using its class name ("employee" in your case) by default.  See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) section of the reference manual for details.

Comment: @ShinichiKai Very good explanation! I had missed that part of the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="empl" action="validate"></form>
```

in form instead of

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="empl" action="validate">
```

Comment: Not sure exactly why this? AFAIK, both the `modelAttribute` and `commandName` are same.