# How does @ModelAttribute send data to jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute, model-view

I have a query. I am using `@ModelAttribute` on a function in a `formController`.

```
@ModelAttribute("modelAttrVar")
public ModelAttr function(){
    ModelAttr obj = new ModelAttr();
    //...code
    return obj;
}
```

But this model attribute is not added to the ModelAndView I am returning.....

```
public ModelAndView func2(){
    ModelAndView obj = new ModelAndView();
    obj.addAttribute("variableName" , value);
    obj.setViewName("viewName");
    return obj;
}
```

Now when I see the jsp then the model Attribute variable `modelAttrVar` is available in jsp and is giving values. How ??

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2):

There's something not clear!

The `@ModelAttribute` annotation is used to bind a form inside a jsp to a controller, in order to have all the fields, written inside an html form, available in a Controller.

[What is @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc)

So basically a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` should be work as `landing point` method, after a post request (form submit).

So let's take an example, you have a POJO with two variable:

```
public class ModelAttrExample {

String name;
String lastName;

///getter and setter...
}
```

a JSP  indexForm.jsp

```
<form:form action="/greeting" >
 <form:input path="name" />
 <form:input path="lastName" />

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

and a SpringController

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("", new ModelAttrExample ());
    return "indexForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute ModelAttrExample example, Model model) {

   example.getName();//same form value
   example.getLastName(); //same form value
   //do your logic here...
   }
}
```

Once the form is submitted the `greetingSubmit()` method is triggered, and an instance of the `ModelAttrExample`, filled with the datas of the form, will be available inside the method.

so... @ModelAttribute is used to take the values from a html form field and put this datas  inside an  class instance variables.

I suggest you to follow this tutorial from [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/),
It is very well written and very easy to understand

If you need more info do not hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thanks Sir... for your reply. Actually the case is when we open a record from list screen . The call goes to FormController and there it goes to modelAttribute function @ModelAttribute("modelAttrVar")

public ModelAttr function(){}   

which extracts the particular record from db. Then after  func2() we receive modelAndView and then finally go to jsp. And Then in jsp we get the modelAttrVar model Attribute like ${modelAttrVar.var1} .

Comment: So means when opening a record we never add this modelAttrVar to ModelAndView but it still goes to jsp and data from modelAttrVar object fills up the relevant fields on jsp page. How?

Comment: I'm still not understanding your flow, you said "Then after func2() we receive modelAndView", who is calling func2() ? How do you receive model and view in that method? If you need just to show a record selectec from a list, for example you could trigger a method passing via get the id, take the datas from the db and than render the extracted value with  model.addAttribute("modelAttrVar", youExtracteInstanceOfmodelAttrVar ); and then in the jsp take the values with ${modelAttrVar.var1}, please show the entire code and explain exactly what do you need to do