# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Model Attribute passing HTML tag to HTML Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I pass out HTML tags using Model Attribute like so it passes incorrectly leaving whats not desired

---

```
@Controller
String rating = "<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>"

model.addAttribute("rating", rating);
```

---

```
HTML Page
<span th:text="${rating}"></span>
```

---

```
Result is 
"<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>"
```

As we can see there are quotes around my desired string, which dont show up on other strings such as header, text or int's when passed. Seems to just show up for HTML, when its tags are present

When i pass in a single awesome font it appears the way it should, until you from inspect element hit "edit as HTML"

```
<span>&lt;i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</span>
```

Thanks anyone who knows why or a way around

Comment: First try looking at this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Ok Im gonna read it now. Also amended my post a bit

Comment: Have you tried `th:utext`? http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text

Comment: Your a genius. Worked perfectly. Thanks so much man. Was impossible find solution ! Why not use this as a answer and ill rate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the th:text attribute. If you want Thymeleaf to respect our XHTML tags and not escape them, you will have to use a different attribute: th:utext (for “unescaped text”);)

```
<p th:utext="#{home.welcome}">Welcome to our grocery store!</p>
This will output our message just like we wanted it:
<p>Welcome to our <b>fantastic</b> grocery store!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. That was the solution. Much appreciated your help