# Restangular call function of RestController with @ModelAttribute atttribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

I called the `getUser` in my app **angularJS** with **Restangular** service

`Controller.java`:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
    public List<User> getUser(@ModelAttribute User user){
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        list.add(user);
        return list;
    }
```

and in the **angularJs** :

```
var listUser= Restangular.all('path/user'); 
    var getMutafeUtente = function(){

        return listUser.getList().$object;
    }
```

runing the app i could enter to the getUser method and my user is setted perfectly in the list.

But arriving in angular with an empty list.

I tried with other method that uses the same logic and worked.

The only difference is that in getUser method there is the `@ModelAttribute`.

How can i pass attribut in session to **AngularJs** controller and then to my **html** page?

Answer (score 0):

@ModelAttribute is used for Spring MVC ([What is @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc?rq=1))
You don't need that for communicating with AngularJS through REST

```
 public List<User> getUser(@RequestBody User user){
```

Comment: and if the user is an object  in session getted from another controller. How can i pass it to the controller that interface with angularJs?

Comment: i got as response a non elaborated data:[{"user_id":"userID","name":"name","surname":"surname","email":"NULL"}]

Comment: maybe because that restangular doesn't accept null value in JSon response:
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1257