# ModelAttribute not visible in Swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using `Spring 2.3` and imported swagged using

```
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0')
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0')
```

I want to accept pagination params from the UI, and the model is

```
@Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmPaginationParameters.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmPaginationParameters.class)
public interface PaginationParameters {
    Integer getLimit();
    Integer getOffset();
}
```

In the controller I have declared the method as

```
    @GetMapping("/preview")
    @NonNull
    ResponseEntity<List<SomeDto>> getPreviewResults(@PathVariable final String projectId,
                                                    @ModelAttribute final PaginationParameters params) {
```

However, the same does not get reflected in the Swagger UI.

[image]
[image]

I tried converting it into a post mapping and add `@Valid` too in front of `PaginationParameters` but the same thing. Checked the API docs, again no sign of pagination params. I checked the post [What is @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc) and this way of defining modelAttribute looks sufficient. Not sure I have to declare something different in the PaginationParams class.

Answer (score 2):

Try using @RequestBody along with @ApiParam instead of @ModelAttribute, also use @Postmapping as you are passing request body :-

```
@PostMapping("/preview")
@NonNull
ResponseEntity<List<SomeDto>> getPreviewResults(@ApiParam @PathVariable final String projectId,
                                                @ApiParam @RequestBody final PaginationParameters params) {
```

Comment: But @Gaurav this actually is a use case for making a request, so ideally i shouldn't have to convert it to post. Is there no way we can achieve the same with ModelAttribute?

Comment: whenever we make a request and when the request have body we should go with PostMapping and in case of REST APIs best practice is to use RequestBody to map the request object

Comment: yeah so that's why I was hoping to `ModelAttribute` instead of RequestBody to keep it `GET` request conventionally.

Comment: with GET it won't work for swagger, you will have to change it to POST.

Comment: actually it does, I posted the solution above. Immutables are not supported :(

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that ModelAttribute doesn't work well with `Immutable` class. After changing it to lombok, it worked

```
@Data
public class PaginationParameters {
    private Integer limit;
    private Integer offset;
}
```

Comment: This comment doesn't answer the actual problem. This is nothing to do with lombok.