# Spring MVC @ModelAttribute as a method parameter annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I bumped into an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423501/14806310) about the usage of `@ModelAttribute` on spring MVC here on stackoverflow, and learned that it was not actually required to be added into the method's parameter.

I looked for some controllers from our old project, deleted the annotation, and surprisingly the application still runs flawlessly without the `@ModelAttribute`. Please see example below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/audit/filter")
public String getAuditLogsWithFilter(Model model, AuditLogFilter auditLogFilter, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

I have read some articles about it but I can not grasp onto why `@ModelAttribute` is used for some method parameters particularly for spring controllers.

Can anybody provide a simple explanation into why that is? Or can someone enumerate some cases into which I should add the `@ModelAttribute` annotation to my parameter object?

Answer (score 2):

as described in the [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args), it's optional:

> Note that using @ModelAttribute is optional (for example, to set its attributes). By default, any argument that is not a simple value type (as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty) and is not resolved by any other argument resolver is treated as if it were annotated with @ModelAttribute.